# Python Tkinker events

Tags: python, tkinter

I would want to use time to enable event's callback function in Tkinter.

How do I do something like this using Tkinter

```
ftime  = time()
while 1:
    if ftime - time() > 2000:
        dosomething
        ftime = time()
```

Note that all I wanted is being able to use time passed to call callback function

Janus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Tkinter method [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to schedule a command to run after a given number of milliseconds. That's considerably better than implementing a tight loop. Remember: the event loop is already an infinite loop, nesting a long running loop inside it causes performance problems.

If you want something to be called more than once after a given period of time you can have a job call itself at regular intervals. There is an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter/2401181#2401181) to the question [How to create a timer using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter)