# tkinter and time.sleep

Tags: python, time, tkinter, sleep, elapsedtime

I am trying to delete text inside a text box after waiting 5 seconds, but instead the program wont run and does sleep over everything else. Also is there a way for me to just make my textbox sleep so i can run other code while the text is frozen?

```
from time import time, sleep
from Tkinter import *

def empty_textbox():
    textbox.insert(END, 'This is a test')
    sleep(5)
    textbox.delete("1.0", END)

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=100)
textbox = Text(frame)

frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack()
textbox.pack()

empty_textbox()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You really should be using something like the Tkinter [after method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/universal.html) rather than `time.sleep(...)`.

There's an example of using the after method at this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter).

Here's a modified version of your script that uses the after method:

```
from time import time, sleep
from Tkinter import *

def empty_textbox():
    textbox.delete("1.0", END)

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=100)
textbox = Text(frame)

frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack()
textbox.pack()

textbox.insert(END, 'This is a test')
textbox.after(5000, empty_textbox)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can emulate `time.sleep` in tkinter. For this we still need to use the `.after` method to run our code [alongside the mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459083/13629335), but we could add readability to our code with a `sleep` function. To add the desired behavior, tkinter provides another underestimated feature, `wait_variable`. `wait_variable` stops the codeblock till the variable is set and thus can be scheduled with `after`.

```
def tksleep(t):
    'emulating time.sleep(seconds)'
    ms = int(t*1000)
    root = tk._get_default_root('sleep')
    var = tk.IntVar(root)
    root.after(ms, var.set, 1)
    root.wait_variable(var)
```

Real world examples:

- [update a Label to display a clock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74162331/13629335) *while-loop*
- [animated writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74218331/13629335) *nested for-loops*

Limitation:

- tkinter [does not quit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253534/13629335) while `tksleep` is used.

  - Make sure there is no pending tksleep by exiting the application.
- Using tksleep casually can lead to [unintended behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74370984/13629335)

---

### UPDATE

[TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard) worked out something superior to the code above [here](https://pastebin.com/df0ZPa2w). Instead of [tkwait](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/tkwait.html) command he uses the `mainloop` and this overcomes the bug of not quitting the process as described above, but still can lead to unintended output, depending on what you expect:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def tksleep(self, time:float) -> None:
    """
    Emulating `time.sleep(seconds)`
    Created by TheLizzard, inspired by Thingamabobs
    """
    self.after(int(time*1000), self.quit)
    self.mainloop()
tk.Misc.tksleep = tksleep

# Example
root = tk.Tk()
root.tksleep(2)
```

Comment: So, in the update section, you have to create a new `tk.Tk()` every time to use the `tksleep` method?
And doesn't the `mainloop` of that new `tk.Tk()` instance still block the whole execution? If not, why? Doesn't it all use the normal single thread?