# Python - Tkinter - Fun with place()

Tags: python, tkinter

So there I was just messing around in an interpreter when I came across a strange problem. I was just trying to make a bouncing smiley face to brighten my day, but for some reason I'm unable to do this. And I have no desire to do this in Pygame, if anyone thinks to suggest that. This isn't a project, it was just something silly I was doing and don't understand why it's not working.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time,random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.mainloop()
bouncer = Label(root, text="=D")

def bounce ():
    X = random.randint(1,500)
    Y = random.randint(1,500)
    bouncer.place(x=X, y=Y)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    bounce()
```

This code does not work, and I for the life of me can't figure out why. What ends up happening is the loop runs forever, and when I ^C bounce() gets called once and the script ends. I tried it in a for loop to see if I could just bounce 100 times, but bounce() would just call once after the loop finished. I'm fairly stumped on this.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: You never do `import random`, and you should remove the comma between time and sleep.. it should be `time.sleep` shouldn't it?

Comment: Was just a brain fart. Fixed, thanks. :)

Comment: I don't think it was fixed.

Comment: I import time and random. My brain fart was typing import time,sleep instead of import time,random. :P

Comment: I think you forgot `root.mainloop`

Comment: The reason nothing is showing up is because of time.sleep(). That makes the whole UI loop sleep. See these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/python-time-sleep and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks. That's what I get for typing hastily. Doesn't fix the problem, but does fix the answer. mainloop() isn't needed when working in an interpreter with Tkinter.

Comment: @rbk No, it's because he's not calling root.mainloop I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sleep` puts the process to the sleep state. Better use `after`.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time,random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
bouncer = Label(root, text="=D")

def bounce ():
    X = random.randint(1,500)
    Y = random.randint(1,500)
    bouncer.place(x=X, y=Y)
    root.after(1000, bounce)

bounce()
root.mainloop()
```