# Making a tkinter memory game

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a memory game in Tkinter. However, I am at the point where I'm trying to flip cards over. The first card works, it flips over. Then the second card doesn't flip over, maybe immediately flips over again. Can you please help me

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from random import randint
from random import shuffle
win = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, text):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.text = text
    def drawFaceDown(self):
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        self.isFaceUp = False
    def drawFaceUp(self):
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 70, self.y + 70, fill = "blue")
        canvas.create_text(self.x + 35, self.y + 35, text = self.text, width = 70)
        self.isFaceUp = True
    def isUnderMouse(self, event):
        if(event.x > self.x and event.x < self.x + 70):
            if(event.y > self.y and event.y < self.y + 70):
                return True

tiles = []
colors = [
    "Red",
    "Orange",
    "Yellow",
    "Green",
    "Blue",
    "Purple",
    "Pink",
    "Brown",
    "Black",
    "Gray",
    "Magenta",
    "Maroon"
]

selected = []
for i in range(10):
    randomInd = randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
    color = colors[randomInd]
    selected.append(color)
    selected.append(color)
    del colors[randomInd]
shuffle(selected)

flippedTiles = []

def mouseClicked(self):
    global numFlipped
    global flippedTiles
    for i in range(len(tiles)):
        if tiles[i].isUnderMouse(self):
            if (len(flippedTiles) < 2 and not(tiles[i].isFaceUp)) :
                tiles[i].drawFaceUp()
                flippedTiles.append(tiles[i])
            if (len(flippedTiles) == 2):
                if not(flippedTiles[0].text == flippedTiles[1].text):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    flippedTiles[0].drawFaceDown()
                    flippedTiles[1].drawFaceDown()

NUM_COLS = 5
NUM_ROWS = 4

for x in range(0,NUM_COLS):
    for y in range(0,NUM_ROWS):
            tiles.append(Tile(x * 78 + 10, y * 78 + 40, selected.pop()))

for i in range(len(tiles)):
    tiles[i].drawFaceDown()

win.bind("<Button-1>", mouseClicked)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Playing around with your program a little bit, your program stops after one card is pressed, or if a second matching card is found. Interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are changing tile's face up/face down state you are not clearing  `flippedTiles`. Also, if both are correct, correct ones should stay in `flippedTiles` hence after a match, `len(flippedTiles)` will not go under 2. To solve it, you should track number of tiles flipped that turn and set it to zero after two clicks.

By the way, [you should not use `sleep` with `tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/python-time-sleep). There is `after` method instead.

```
flippedThisTurn = 0
def mouseClicked(event):
    global flippedTiles
    global flippedThisTurn
    for tile in tiles:
        if tile.isUnderMouse(event):
            if (not(tile.isFaceUp)) :
                tile.drawFaceUp()
                flippedTiles.append(tile)
                flippedThisTurn += 1

            if (flippedThisTurn == 2):
                win.after(1000, checkTiles)
                flippedThisTurn = 0

def checkTiles():
    if not(flippedTiles[-1].text == flippedTiles[-2].text): #check last two elements
        flippedTiles[-1].drawFaceDown() #facedown last two elements
        flippedTiles[-2].drawFaceDown()
        del flippedTiles[-2:] #remove last two elements
```