# Python 2.7 Tkinter on Windows doesn't respond

Tags: python, tkinter

I have got a problem with Tkinter. I made a GUI with two lists. On my Mac OS X everything works fine but on Windows my program is working but Tkinter GUI doesn't respond. I read about this and my problem probably is in time.sleep(10) what do I need to use to make a function delay?
In my opinion Tkinter doesn't like time.sleep.

```
def showCars3():
while True:
    global hotList
    print("")   
    hotList.delete(0, END)
    for car in hotCars:
        hotList.insert(END, car.title)
    hotList.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(10)


t5 = Thread(target = showCars3)
```

Comment: To my knowledge, Tkinter isn't thread safe. If you make changes to the GUI, make them from the thread that's running the Tkinter mainloop.

Comment: Why do you need the gui to sleep? Isn't the real problem you're trying to solve is how to insert values every 10 seconds? You don't need to sleep to do that.

Comment: Use python 3. Also, in python functions and variables are named using `lowercase_with_underscores` not camelCase.

Comment: And see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/tkinter-and-time-sleep

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have not defined the Tkinter window?

And your indentation is messed:

**Yours:**

```py
def showCars3():
while True:
    global hotList
    print("")   
    hotList.delete(0, END)
    for car in hotCars:
        hotList.insert(END, car.title)
    hotList.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(10)
```

**Needed Indentations:**

```py
def showCars3():
    while True:
        global hotList
        print("")   
        hotList.delete(0, END)
        for car in hotCars:
            hotList.insert(END, car.title)
        hotList.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(10)
```

And no, Tkinter is fine with time.sleep.

If those do not solve your problem, you then need to show me your whole code.

Comment: You need to clarify your answer a bit. Tkinter is definitely _not_ fine with sleep. If you put the sleep in another thread it's ok, but if it's in the same thread as the GUI it will cause the UI to freeze.

Comment: Mine works really well with time.sleep.

Answer (score -2):

Have you got:

```
import time
```

somewhere above your code?

Comment: This is no my problem. I have got this.