# flash text color for 2 seconds in python

Tags: python, text, colors, label, flashing

new to coding and attemping to make a score board program for when a goal is scored I want text color to change then after 2 seconds revert back to original color. I added a 2 second sleep function but it seems to delay the entire process and not the color change.

```
     # def actions that will take place when away team scores
     def a_goal():
          global awayscore
          awayscore += 1
          Label(main, text=awayscore, font='TkFixedFont 50 bold', fg='red', background= 'black').place(x=100, y=100)
          time.sleep(2)
          Label(main, text=awayscore, font='TkFixedFont 50 bold', fg='orange', background= 'black').place(x=100, y=100)
```

Comment: Tkinter doesn't work as expected with `time.sleep()`, look into the tkinter `after` function

Comment: Take a look into this [question about tkinter and time.sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/python-time-sleep)