# Tkinter - Having one function running at the background at all time while others are free to execute?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pyautogui

Im looking for a way to implement a function that would be running endlessly, while other functions, that would be called by pressing buttons, would not disrupt this functions flow and vice versa => 2 and possibly more functions running at the same time.

Comment: ***"mouseMove function executes first"***: The reason is using `time.sleep(1)`. Read [tkinter and time.sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10393929/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl remove time.sleep(1) and the function still dont run asynchronously. The mouseMove function still executes first

Comment: ***The mouseMove function still executes first"***: As it stands, there is no reason to do so, verified i get first `move()`. ***"still dont run asynchronously."***: How do you expect **async** using `lambda:`? [Edit] your question and explain in detail, using a [mcve], what you realy want to accomplish.

Comment: @stovfl I will completly rephrase the question and the post itself so you can understand it better.

Comment: You want to [use threads to preventing main event loop from “freezing”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747734/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl i will look into that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module to run something on a different thread so the main event loop won't freeze.

1. Import the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module

```py
import threading
```

2. Create a function you want the new thread to run
3. Create a new thread and pass in the function you created

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=arguments)
```

Where `target` is the function you want to call in this new tread, and `args` are the arguments you need to pass into your function (you can leave `args` out if there are no arguments to pass in)

4. Run the new thread

```py
thread.start()
```