# Character Animation in python not working

Tags: python, tkinter, sleep

I am busy making a game in python using tkinter, time and PIL, and I have a character that I want to animate very simply, but when I try this code, it doesn't do anything then jumps to the last image, can someone please tell me why this is?

```
def move_char(event):
if event.keysym == "w":
    character = ch1
    c.delete(character)
    character = ch2_1
    c.create_image(725, 450, image = character)
    sleep(0.2)
    c.delete(character)
    character = ch2
    c.create_image(725, 450, image = character)
    sleep(0.2)
    c.delete(character)
    character = ch2_2
    c.create_image(725, 450, image = character)
    sleep(0.2)
    c.delete(character)
    character = ch2
    c.create_image(725, 450, image = character)
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Reading [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) will be help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter and time.sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/tkinter-and-time-sleep)

Comment: I'm afraid that if I use the examples in Tkinter understanding mainloop, my program crashes, and PhotoImage (class of character) has no after method, so if I use c.after(), it has the same problem

Comment: Base on your code, `c` is a `Canvas`, and `ch1`, `ch2`, `ch2_1` and `ch2_2` are instances of `PhotoImage` or `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`.  So `c.delete(character)` will not delete the image in the canvas.  In order to see the effect, you need to add `c.update()` after each `c.create_image(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `character` is a reference to `PhotoImage`, `c.delete(character)` will not delete the image in the canvas as you wish.  You can use `tag` option of `c.create_image(...)` to identify the image and use the tag in `c.delete()`.  Also in order to see the animation effect, you need to call `c.update()` after `c.create_image(...)`.

Below is an updated `move_char(...)`:

```
def move_char(event):
    if event.keysym == "w":
        # loop through the images
        for ch in (ch2_1, ch2, ch2_2, ch2):
            c.delete('char-image') # remove current image
            c.create_image(725, 450, image=ch, tag='char-image') # use tag to identify image
            c.update() # make the change effective
            sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you, the only problem I still have is that the original picture is always showing in the background, but i'm guessing this is to do with the way I have placed him. :)

Comment: Do you mean image `ch1`? Just create the image with `tag='char-image'` as well.

Comment: Thank you, I did try this but I did an oopsie and used an underscore instead of a dash, but that is now fixed haha, appreciate your help :)