# Tkinter code for a Timer is crashing the app (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, timer, crash

I am creating a timer for my quiz app and I decided to try it out first in a separate program,
however when I run the following code and press the 'start timer' button the app simply stops responding
and I am forced to close it through the task manager

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root=Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300,200))

lb=Label(root,text='')
lb.pack()

def func(h,m,s):

    lb.config(text=str(h)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(s))
    time.sleep(1)
    s+=1

    func(h,m,s)
    if s==59:
        m=1
        s=0

bt=Button(root,text='start timer',command=lambda:func(0,0,0))
bt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do not use `time.sleep` with tkinter. Use `root.after` instead. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10393929/7519434) for more information.

Comment: @Henry didn't help

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i replaced time.sleep(1) with root.after(1000, func1) and I put s+=1 in func1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `root.after` instead of `time.sleep`. Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401181/7519434) about making a timer. This is what it looks like applied to your code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root=Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300,200))

lb=Label(root,text='')
lb.pack()

def func(h,m,s):

    lb.config(text=str(h)+':'+str(m)+':'+str(s))
    s+=1
    if s==59:
        m=1
        s=0
    root.after(1000, lambda: func(h,m,s))

bt=Button(root,text='start timer',command=lambda:func(0,0,0))
bt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```