# Firstly I want to place label1 and after 3 seconds i want to configure background but it doesnt work

Tags: python, tkinter, sleep

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
root=tk.Tk()
label1=tk.Label(text='hello',font='Calibri 25')
label1.pack()
time.sleep(3)
label1.configure(bg='green')
root.mainloop()
```

Again and again I say only I want to place label1 and after 3 seconds I want to change the background color but it doesnt work. Can you explain me the main problem and what can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter and time.sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393886/tkinter-and-time-sleep)

Answer (score 2):

`sleep` should not be used in the main tkinter loop, as this causes the interface to freeze. It's better to use `after`.

```
import tkinter as tk

COLOR = 'green'

def lbl_clear():
    label1.configure(text="", bg=root['bg'])
    

def lbl_bg(color):
    label1.configure(bg=color)
    root.after(3000, lbl_clear)


root = tk.Tk()
label1 = tk.Label(text='hello', font='Calibri 25')
label1.pack()
root.after(3000, lbl_bg, COLOR)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am new at this job please forgive me but what does after_cancel means?

Comment: ı have one question more how can i remove the label after three seconds without destroy label

Comment: @Mehmet Kılınçkaya
Universal widget methods https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html

Comment: @Mehmet Kılınçkaya I have added the code.

Comment: You are a big king thx bro

Comment: If you only want to remove the text then remove `bg=root['bg']`.