# Calling an external function that contains 'time.sleep()' within a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to call an external function from the press of a button in a Tkinter GUI; the function 'insert's into a Text element. This works perfectly; as long as it is not followed closely by time.sleep(). If it isn't followed, the text updates correctly; if it is, the text does not update, though the function still seems to be running the loop, as it will happily print text to the console.

Here's my example script:

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def test_function(gui_self):
    while True:
        print "Debug message"
        gui_self.main_.insert(END, "Test")


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, width=300, height=500)
        frame.pack()
        self.main_ = Entry(frame, width=80, justify=CENTER)
        self.main_.pack()

        test_function(self)

root = Tk()
application = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This works well. However, changing test_function to the following seems to mess things up:

```
def test_function(gui_self):
    while True:
        print "Debug message"
        gui_self.main_.insert(END, "Test")
        sleep(5)
```

Any suggestions to fix whatever it is that I am doing wrong here? I'm sure it's just an issue that I, as a fairly basic level user, am not using the correct syntax for.

As a side note, the 'sleep' command also seems to freeze the program entirely, which I find rather annoying and unattractive. Is there a method to pause the loop for a variably set (eg, var = 1(second)) amount of time, other than 'pipe'ing threads, that would be efficient and more.. clean?

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on event loops. Basically, while the program is stuck inside your function, it can't update the GUI. There's a good resource for tkinter here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely agree with Nick Craig-Wood's answer -- don't put the main thread of your gui to sleep.  Generally, you want to call `after` which registers a function to be called after (approximately) X milliseconds.  Here's an example that will call `test_function` every 5 seconds.  Every time test_function is called, it will re-register itself to be called 5 seconds later.

```
def test_function(gui_self):
    print "Debug message"
    gui_self.main_.insert(END, "Test")
    gui_self.after(5000,test_function,gui_self)
    #the line below also should work.  As long as the item is a Tkinter widget
    #gui_self.main_.after(5000,test_function,gui_self)
```

Also, completely unrelated, (but as a matter of style) -- is there a reason you're using `main_` in `GUI` instead of just `main`?  Generally, trailing underscores are appended to aviod name-clashes with python keywords.  As far as I know, `main` isn't a keyword.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to stop the program from crashing entirely :) I used trailing _ in this case, as I already have a 'main' included from an import :) (It is an annoying function name, but I wrote the import when I very first started learning python. You just reminded me to change it. Thanks again.

Comment: @abkai -- Even if you do `from module import main`, you can still have a class which has an attribute named `main`.

Comment: Oh, I suppose that's true when I think about it haha. Force of habit, when I wrote my script I didn't write it within a class, then I moved it into one in attempt to neaten my work, I didn't even think to change it; still learning python :P

Answer (score 3):

In general don't call `time.sleep` in a single threaded GUI otherwise you'll cause it to block as you've discovered.

The correct way to deal with sleeps is to use GUI events.

See this example in [another Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter) question which shows how to use the `after` method all TK root windows have.