# In a multithreading program,there are interruption with the error description Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

Tags: python, multithreading

In the program I use multithreadings. But I don't know whether it's the key to cause the problem. For the package, there are matplotlib,numpy,cartopy,threading. As the program runs,the mouse point becomes a spinning circle. Sometimes it is interrupted, and gets the error description:

> Tcl_AttemptSetObjLength called with shared object. This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information. Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

Comment: I could reach this error message using and abusing a multiprocessing matplotlib example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/multiprocess_sgskip.html - in the `__call__` I commented out the `plt.show()`. My idea is that the interpreter tries to wake the process with the timer but that is already finished. (I have no idea whether I'm right.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python tkinter with threading causing crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168346/python-tkinter-with-threading-causing-crash)