# How to allow a function to only be called once a minute in python / tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a button that executes a function (in tkinter). Let's say it adds money in a video game.  So when you press that button, you get 100 dollars.  However, I only want my user to be able to add 100 dollars once per minute.  Is there a way to only allow a function to be called once a minute? (maybe with the time module or something?)

The most i know about managing time in a function is this, I would like to do something along these lines:

```
def add_money():
money = money + 100
app.after(5000, add_money)
```

I know that this function would obviously not get what i want. Is there a way to implement it so that if you clicked the button and a minute had not passed, the program would do nothing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code a timer in a python GUI in TKinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter) and all the others one gets with search for `tkinter` and `timer`.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the timer options. This question is about how to disable functionality for a period of time. While that is done using the same mechanism as a timer, it's different enough to be worth keeping open, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just track time yourself, and do nothing if too little time has elapsed.

```
def add_money():
    curr_time = int(time.time())
    if curr_time - app.last_time > 60:
        app.last_time = curr_time
        money = money + 100
```

This way, the function can be called as often as the user likes, but it will only do what he wants once a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually likely implement this as a decorator as it sounds like something reusable. The sample below allows you to reuse `guarded` on any function you want, specifying the timeout (in seconds) for each function you use the decorator on:

```
import time
from functools import wraps

_guards = {}

def guarded(tm):
    def wrapper(fn):
        _guards[fn] = {'timeout': tm} 
        @wraps(fn)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            t = time.time()
            if 'last' not in _guards[fn] or \
                t - _guards[fn]['last'] > _guards[fn]['timeout']:
                _guards[fn]['last'] = t 
                fn(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner
    return wrapper

money = 0 
@guarded(2)
def add_money():
    global money
    money += 100 
    print money
```

Here, `add_money` is only allowed after a 2 second timeout:

```
In [2]: add_money()
100
In [3]: add_money()
In [4]: add_money()
200
In [5]: add_money()
In [6]: add_money()
In [7]: add_money()
In [8]: add_money()
300
```

Yes, there are arguments for not using a global dict to track this stuff (bad when running multithreaded) and to use `threading.local` instead, but that's kinda outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: while this is functional, from a user experience point of view it's not a good solution. In addition to disallowing the function, the UI should give some sort of feedback -- either disable the button or show a message saying the action is disallowed, etc. So, while the decorator is interesting, I think it might be difficult to use (or re-use) if you want to do some UI actions when then function is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In the add_money function, disable the "add money" button, and then schedule it to be re-enabled after one minute:

```
def add_money():
    <do the real work here>

    add_money_button.configure(state="disabled")
    root.after(60000, lambda: add_money_button.configure(state="normal"))
```

If your app has multiple ways to add money, such as a menu item, a button, and an accelerator key, create a function that enables or disables all of those items, then call that function via `after`.