# Pausing Python Tkinter Program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a card matching game using python, and I need it so that when two cards are selected, they are shown for a few seconds and then the code executes to get rid of them or return them. I have tried using time.sleep, however this just freezes my program without displaying the second card. Are there any other modules or techniques I can use to make this happen?

Comment: please show us some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have over 800 lines of code, so that is not really a option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time.sleep suspends the program. Since events are still being pumped, there is nothing to process the event.

Take a look at this: 
[How to create a timer using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter)