# Getting a function to execute periodically

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a simple project and I need a little help. I have created a program that draws circles on a canvas. The circles are blue, and the method flash() takes a random int count, and will light up a circle and change its color to yellow. The problem is I want the function to continue to execute every second or so, because I want to eventually be able to let the user of the program click onto the circle that is lit, and have the program respond with dialog stating Correct/Incorrect if the user got it right. As of right now I can only get it to light one circle and that is it. I tried using a thread and set it to every 2 seconds, but that didn't work or maybe I didn't do something correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from graphics import *
from tkinter import *
import random
class App():
    def __init__(self):            
        self.win = GraphWin('Demo2', 400, 300) # give title and dimensions
        count = random.randint(1,9)        
        self.flash(count)

    def flash(self,count):
        circle1 = Circle(Point(50,30), 25) # set center and radius
        circle2 = Circle(Point(110,30), 25)
        circle3 = Circle(Point(170,30),25)
        circle4 = Circle(Point(50,90),25)
        circle5 = Circle(Point(110,90),25)
        circle6 = Circle(Point(170,90),25)
        circle7 = Circle(Point(50,150),25)
        circle8 = Circle(Point(110,150),25)
        circle9 = Circle(Point(170,150),25)
        circle1.setFill("blue")
        circle1.draw(self.win)
        circle2.setFill("blue")
        circle2.draw(self.win)
        circle3.setFill("blue")
        circle3.draw(self.win)
        circle4.setFill("blue")
        circle4.draw(self.win)
        circle5.setFill("blue") 
        circle5.draw(self.win)
        circle6.setFill("blue")
        circle6.draw(self.win)
        circle7.setFill("blue")
        circle7.draw(self.win)
        circle8.setFill("blue")
        circle8.draw(self.win)
        circle9.setFill("blue")
        circle9.draw(self.win)
        if count==1:
            circle1.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 29 and mouseClick.y <= 31 and mouseClick.x >= 49 and mouseClick.x <= 51:
             print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        elif count==2:
            circle2.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 29 and mouseClick.y <= 31 and mouseClick.x >= 109 and mouseClick.x <= 111:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        elif count==3:
            circle1.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 29 and mouseClick.y <= 31 and mouseClick.x >= 169 and mouseClick.x <= 171:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")

        elif count==4:
            circle4.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 89 and mouseClick.y <= 91 and mouseClick.x >= 49 and mouseClick.x <= 51:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        elif count==5:
            circle5.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 89 and mouseClick.y <= 91 and mouseClick.x >= 109 and mouseClick.x <= 111:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        elif count==6:
            circle6.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 89 and mouseClick.y <= 91 and mouseClick.x >= 169 and mouseClick.x <= 171:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        elif count==7:
            circle7.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 149 and mouseClick.y <= 151 and mouseClick.x >= 49 and mouseClick.x <= 51:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        elif count==8:
            circle8.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 149 and mouseClick.y <= 151 and mouseClick.x >= 109 and mouseClick.x <= 111:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")
        else:
            circle9.setFill("yellow")
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse()
            if mouseClick.y >= 149 and mouseClick.y <= 151 and mouseClick.x >= 169 and mouseClick.x <= 171:
                print("Correct")
            else:
                print("Incorrect")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have already viewed that post and I have tried that solution to no avail. Have you tried to run my code so you can see what I am talking about?

Comment: Have you read the answers too? You've mentioned only that you've tried a thread based solution. I can't run your code because I don't have the `graphics` module.

Comment: The [Code a timer in a python GUI in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400262/7432) question has the right solution. You say you tried it to no avail, but the code in your question doesn't show that you tried it.

Comment: Bryan Oakley I appreciate the suggestion, but I did indeed try that. It was actually the first solution that I tried. Have you tried running my program using this method and did you get it to work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

okay, so you may want to try this:
put this in your code somewhere in the beginning `import time`
then, where ever you want a delay, you use this:`time.sleep(number of seconds)`
you can include milliseconds in it by typing the amount of seconds as .1 or something
if you want it to repeat every few seconds, you do this

```
while True:
    flash(self,count) #replace self and count with whatever you want
    time.sleep(x) #replace x with amount of seconds, this part is optional though.
```

the `while True:` makes it loop while `True == True` a.k.a. forever. if you only want it to loop a certain amount of times, do something like this

```
max=6 #6 is the amount of times you want it to loop
loop_count=1 # this is required for later in the loop
while x <=max: #loops ONLY when x is less than or equal to 6
    flash(self,count) #replace self and count with whatever you want
    time.sleep(y) #this part is only if you want it to delay at all.
    loop_count+=1 #this makes it so that every time the loop runs, loop_count gains 1. 
    # after it runs the first time, loop_count == 2 (which means it is starting its second loop)
```

i hope this made sense to you and that i could help. if there are any errors please correct me

Comment: Where exactly do you suggest I put the while loop? I tried a could of different places and it doesn't get the job done, so I don't know if there is something wrong with the way it is coded or what. Have you tried to run my code and seen what I talking about? Everything runs fine, I just need it to CONTINUE to loop so it will keep lighting up random circles

Comment: **This is bad advice**. Never put a sleep in GUI code because it will do just that -- make your program sleep. That means it won't respond to events, it won't refresh the screen, it will be frozen.

Comment: oh srry for the bad advice im not really good with python im not exactly sure how to use graphics and such, so keep looking for advice