# Python/Tkinter: Update button from every second

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm trying to start a thread (without understanding what threads are) that will call a function from a different python file every second, and set a label's text attribute to the str that it returns.  The result would a be a label that every second is updated to show the current time.   I could use a `while True` loop but that would stop the succesive code from running, including Tkinter's `Tk.mainloop()`. I've seen a lot of questions about this topic on SO but haven't gotten any solution to work so far.

What python method can start a process that continually calls an external function?  And should this be before or after the `mainloop()`?  What exactly is that `mainloop()` loop doing?  The python program continues yet somehow Tkinter is still able to check for events?

Running Python 3.4

Comment: Though it's not EXACTLY a duplicate, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter) which is definitely *DUPLICATE-ESQUE*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it. Well no, I'd probably wrap it into a class and instantiate the class but then I'm really just stealing whole-cloth from [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk
import customfunc

def run():
    root = tk.Tk()
    s_var = tk.StringVar()
    tk.Label(root, textvariable = s_var).pack()

    def update_time():
        s_var.set(customfunc.func())
        root.after(1000, update_time)

    update_time()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Where would you put mainloop()?

Comment: @joshsvoss oops, I was testing in IDLE and forgot heh. updated.