# TKinter window crashing when switching to another window (Like Word or Chrome)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I wrote a little app that controls an experiment on a robot over a serial line. I added a TKinter window that gave out a percent completed update. It works great, so long as TKinter stays the active window. As soon as I switch to Word or Chrome, it crashed. Here's an simplified example of what I'm doing

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()
w = Label(master, text="")
w.pack()
def complicatedwhileloop():
    m = 0
    while m < 100:
        texttodisplay = m*m 
        w.config(text=str(texttodisplay))
        master.update_idletasks() 
        m = m+1
        time.sleep(1)
b = Button(master, text="OK", command=complicatedwhileloop)
b.pack()
mainloop()
```

How can I make it so that I can monitor the progress but still use other applications.

Comment: What platform? Also, likely unrelated to the problem (but maybe not...), you should never call sleep in a gui. There are better ways to do what you want involving the use of tkinter's `after` command. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400262/7432

Comment: Putting time.sleep() in any GUI program is almost always a bad idea have you looked at .after()?

Comment: Have you tried `master.mainloop()` ?

Comment: You guys miss understand, the time.sleep(1) is just to simulate all the code that moves the robot arms, takes a sample and writes it to a file. I wanted a compact example, there is no sleep in the real code. @Bryan Windows 7

Comment: I would recommend using a StringVar for the test to make it easier, not what you're looking for but just a suggestion.

Comment: I think I just herped and derped on this code. I'll rewrite it using the after command.

Comment: Doing     root.update_idletasks()
    root.update() 
    root.update_idletasks() seems to fix it