# while loop in Python to update in window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a script and it is meant to insert a variable into the insert field. 
So far, I have been able to create the `while` loop which prints the variable, so i know its working.

The frustrating part is that it doesn't bring up the window, it only prints the variable:

```
import time
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
import urllib2
from ttk import *
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

a= 0
while a<1:

    print a


    class Application(Frame):
            """GUI to display results of 'equity get'"""

            def __init__(self, master):
                """initialise the Frame"""
                Frame.__init__(self,master)
                self.grid()
                self.create_widgets()

            def create_widgets(self):
                """Create button, text and entry Widget"""
                """what it is i.e. label"""


                self.data = Label(self, text ="Data")
                self.data1 = Entry(self, width = 10)


                self.data.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
                self.data1.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
                self.data1.grid(column = 3, row = 1)            
                self.data1.insert(0,a)

app = Application(root)
root.title("reload test")
root.geometry("700x300")
root.mainloop()
```

The version below opens the window but the loop only iterates once, when in reality, i want it to continue all day.

```
import time
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
import urllib2
from ttk import *
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

a= 0
while a<1:

    print a


    class Application(Frame):
            """GUI to display results of 'equity get'"""

            def __init__(self, master):
                """initialise the Frame"""
                Frame.__init__(self,master)
                self.grid()
                self.create_widgets()

            def create_widgets(self):
                """Create button, text and entry Widget"""
                """what it is i.e. label"""


                self.data = Label(self, text ="Data")
                self.data1 = Entry(self, width = 10)


                self.data.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
                self.data1.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
                self.data1.grid(column = 3, row = 1)            
                self.data1.insert(0,a)

    app = Application(root)
    root.title("reload test")
    root.geometry("700x200")
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you @guest for your refernce to using the `after`function, however, I am a little unsure of where it needs to go.

@Wooble the variable `a` will be a webscrape and I want it to insert the live information into my insert field Therefore, it will run a loop and insert what it finds!

Perhaps I am placing the `after` function in the incorrect place!

```
import time
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
import urllib2
from ttk import *
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

a= 0
while a<1:
    url = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ngq14.nym&ql=1"
    request= urllib2.Request(url)
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    content = handle.read()
    splitted_page24 = content.split("<span id=\"yfs_l10_ngq14.nym\">", 1);
    splitted_page24 = splitted_page24[1].split("</span>", 1)
    print splitted_page24[0]


    class Application(Frame):
            """GUI to display results of 'equity get'"""

            def __init__(self, master):
                """initialise the Frame"""
                Frame.__init__(self,master)
                self.grid()
                self.create_widgets()

            def create_widgets(self):
                """Create button, text and entry Widget"""
                """what it is i.e. label"""


                self.data = Label(self, text ="Data")
                self.data1 = Entry(self, width = 10)


                self.data.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
                self.data1.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
                self.data1.grid(column = 3, row = 1)            
                self.data1.insert(0,splitted_page24[0])

    app = Application(root)
    root.title("reload test")
    root.geometry("700x300")
    root.mainloop()
    root.after(15)
```

Comment: It will launch your application again when the mainloop exits. You almost certainly don't want to define a class and run a GUI mainloop in an infinite loop. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It's cause of root.mainloop() which is a loop itself. If you want to do some updates within this loop you can use `after` and a function which handles the update, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/code-a-timer-in-a-python-gui-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the biggest problem in your code is that you're calling `mainloop` inside another loop. That makes no sense whatsoever. Tkinter is designed for you to call `mainloop` exactly once, usually as the last executable line in your program, or last executable line in your main function.

It also doesn't make sense to define a class in a loop. I'm afraid this code needs a complete refactoring.

Finally, the reason you never see the contents of the window is that you aren't requesting that they are made visible. You are creating an instance of `Application`, which is a subclass of `Frame`. However, you neglect to ever call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on that instance, so it stays invisible.