# How to call MessageLoopWork in cefpython?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, cefpython

I made a simple offscreen renderer with [cefpython](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/).

I used `cefpython.MessageLoop()` but I would like to execute a javascript function with `browser.GetFocusedFrame().ExecuteFunction`which must be called from main UI thread.

Is there a way to set a callback on cefpython's message loop?

Alternatively I could use `MessageLoopWork`, but I don't know how. I tried to call it in a separate thread but it does not work:

```
import threading

def main_loop():
    cefpython.MessageLoopWork()
    threading.Timer(0.01, main_loop).start()

threading.Timer(0.01, main_loop).start()
```

I get the following error:

```
[0324/174806:ERROR_REPORT:context.cc(146)] Check failed: false. called on invalid thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cefpython.PostTask() function to post tasks on various CEF threads. See: https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/cefpython#PostTask_(int_threadId,_object_func_[,args..])_(void) and Issue 61. It's available since version 31.0.

The wxpython.py example shows how to use both timer with MessageLoopWork() and MessageLoop().

Comment: Thanks, I saw this function but I don't understand how to use it (I could not find it in wxpython.py).

Comment: @arthur.sw See https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/windows/binaries_32bit/wxpython.py?r=5cf79c6eec11#657

Comment: I successfully implemented your solution, but now I have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29255630/719276), is this related?

Comment: How can I use `cefpython.MessageLoopWork()` without any heavy GUI framework?

Comment: @arthur.sw Another option worth trying is ApplicationSettings.multi_threaded_message_loop. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cefpython/jff7u75Fz7c/Ys_K00xyXoYJ

Comment: The problem is that I'm working on os x and it seems [not possible](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=745)

Comment: @arthur.sw How about using Tkinter? It's a lightweight GUI framework I think and comes with python by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2401181/623622

Comment: @arthur.sw See also PyGUI, lightweight as well: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/

Comment: Thanks for those tips, I'm working on it. Do you know how are coded the update loop of those frameworks? This is the only thing I need ;-)

Comment: I get a `[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe958d6c970` when using `Tkinter` along with `cefpython`, then it stops :-/

Comment: @arthur.sw Are you calling cefpython.Initialize()? I recall similar error, see this issue https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/issues/detail?id=156 . For more cefpython support please use the CEF Python Forum.