# Call a function regularly in the main thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I know how to regularly call a function in a separate thread:

```
def main_loop():
    cefpython.MessageLoopWork() # do something
    threading.Timer(0.01, main_loop).start()

main_loop()
```

But how can I do it in the main thread (`cefpython.MessageLoopWork()` must be called from the main thread).

In the [cefpython](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/) [example](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/windows/binaries_32bit/wxpython.py), it is done with `wxTimer`, but I don't want to use `wxpython`:

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    [...]
    def CreateTimer(self):
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, self.timerID)
        self.timer.Start(10) # 10ms
        wx.EVT_TIMER(self, self.timerID, self.OnTimer)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        cefpython.MessageLoopWork()
```

Comment: Well, you're going to have to use some library built around an event loop. The cefpython documentation has [examples for a bunch of GUI frameworks](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/w/list?q=label:Example), in addition to wxpython.

Comment: I do not want to use big GUI frameworks, but I might have solved my problem thanks to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29239050/719276) (it does not answer this question though)