# Python error; 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'after'

Tags: python, tkinter

I got error while coding in python.
Need to print same random value again & again.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
from random import randint

class App1(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master

        self.label = Label(self , text = "Voltage" , font = ("Helvetica",32))
        self.label.grid(row = 0)

        self.reading_label = Label(self,text = '0.0' , font = ("Helvetica",110))
        self.reading_label.grid(row = 1)
        self.update_reading()


    def update_reading(self):
        value = randint(0,9)
        reading_str = "{:.2f}".format(value)
        self.reading_label.configure(text = reading_str)
        self.master.after(1 , self.update_reading)


root = App1(None)
root.title("Option")
root.geometry("320x240")
root.mainloop()
```

I got error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/voltmeter.py", line 26, in <module>
root = App1(None)
File "/voltmeter.py", line 16, in __init__
self.update_reading()
File "/voltmeter.py", line 23, in update_reading
self.master.after(1 , self.update_reading)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'after'
```

Comment: It looks like you are never initializing `master` to anything since you are passing `None` to the `__init__` method. What type is `master` supposed to be?

Answer (score 4):

You are setting your master variable to `None`, as you are creating the `App1` object by passing parameter as `None` in the following line -

```
root = App1(None)
```

And hence, when you call - `self.master.after(1 , self.update_reading)` , you are getting the `AttributeError` , as self.master is None.

I am not sure what you want to achieve but you can try setting `self.master` to something other than None (whatever you intended it to be).

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory : `self.master` is `None`. It comes from the line

```
 root = App1(None)
```

If you want a timer, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/how-to-create-a-timer-using-tkinter) for instance :

```
self.root.after(1 , self.update_reading)
```