# tkinter: display time in a windows

Tags: python, time, tkinter, display

I am starting with GUI in python with tkinter and I want to display current time as HH:MM:SS in the center of my windows (with big digits if possible). This is the app code: a basic full screen windows with a background picture.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
im = Image.open('spring.png')
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
myvar=Tkinter.Label(root,image = tkimage)
myvar.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit:** By current time I mean to keep updating the time as a clock.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a `compound` parameter to your `myvar` object with value `Tkinter.CENTER` and also a `text`parameter with the time string.
To create time string add

```
import time
time_string = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Now your `myvar` will look like

`myvar=Tkinter.Label(root,image = tkimage, text = time_string, compound = Tkinter.CENTER)`

For further reference see: python time: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

python tkinter label : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

Comment: hi Zeerorg thanks you for help.i did what you say and it is working but it's not what i was expected.it  printing the time when the code run..by "current time" i mean as a clock that update every second.python run  mainloop() as and infinite loop.any idea to keep displaying and updating the current time?

Answer (score 0):

When using place you can use relative coordinates. To place a widget in the center of another widget use `relx` and `relx`. You can tell it which widget to be relative to with the `in_` parameter; by default it will be centered in its parent.

For example:

```
time = tk.Label(...)
time.place(in_=myvar, relx=.5, rely=.5)
```

Having the clock update has been asked many times on stackoverflow. Here's one example: [How to create a timer using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2400262/7432)

Comment: hi Bryan thank you for the answer i went to see the example and as i said i'am just starting with GUI and  Tkinter i don't know much about class also and i am wonrdering if there is any way to include the timer just with a function because i dont know how change the actual code to a class and include the timer.help me please.