# Python 3, using tkinter, trying to create a game where the user has to click a button as many times as they can until the time runs out

Tags: python-3.x, time, tkinter

Basically, I'm trying to make a small game of sorts where the user has to click a button as many times as they can before the time runs out (5 seconds).

After 5 seconds have passed, the button is greyed/disabled. However, my code has trouble working, because the 'timer' works only when the user clicks the button. I want the timer to run regardless of whether the user has clicked the button.

So basically, when the program is run, even if the user hasn't clicked the button and 5 seconds have passed, the button should be greyed/disabled.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.result = 0
        self.grid()
        self.buttonClicks = 0
        self.create_widgets()

    def countTime(self):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.result =self.end - self.start
        return (self.result)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.label = Label(self, text=str(round(self.countTime(),1)))
        self.label.grid()

        self.button1["text"] = "Total clicks: 0"
        self.button1["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button1.grid()

    def update_count(self):
        if(self.countTime() >=5):
            self.button1.configure(state=DISABLED, background='cadetblue')
        else:
            self.buttonClicks+=1
            self.button1["text"] = "Total clicks: " + str(self.buttonClicks)


root = Tk()
root.title("Something")
root.geometry("300x300")

app = GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a timer using the `after()`

```
from tkinter import *
import time
class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.result = 0
        self.grid()
        self.buttonClicks = 0
        self.create_widgets()
        self.isRunning = True
        self.update_clock()
        self.master = master


    def countTime(self):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.result =self.end - self.start
        return self.result

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.label = Label(self, text=str(round(self.countTime(),1)))
        self.label.grid()

        self.button1["text"] = "Total clicks: 0"
        self.button1["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button1.grid()

    def update_count(self):
        if self.isRunning:
            self.buttonClicks+=1
            self.button1["text"] = "Total clicks: " + str(self.buttonClicks)

    def update_clock(self):
        t = round(self.countTime(), 1)
        self.label.configure(text=str(t))
        if t < 5:
            self.master.after(100, self.update_clock)
        else:
            self.isRunning = False


root = Tk()
root.title("Something")
root.geometry("300x300")

app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be running a different thread (As seen here: [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)) to be running the timer.

Check this other question to get an idea on how your other thread should be like [How to create a timer using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/how-to-create-a-timer-using-tkinter)

Comment: this problem definitely doesn't need threads. Threads add considerable complexity, and in this case provide absolutely no value.