# Python: How can I delay the execution of second function by one second

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to know how I can make a delay between executing two functions. The goal is to replace regular, blank button by black after it was on screen for one second. My current program, simplified looks like this, and it just delays the the execution of `CreateInterface()`:

```
class Program(Frame):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title('Test')
        super().__init__(self.root)
        self.grid()
        self.Start()
        return

    def Start(self):
        startbtn=Button(self,width=5, font=('Calibri',16,'bold'), height=2, text='start',command=lambda:self.CreateInterface())
        startbtn.grid(row=1,column=1)

    def CreateInterface(self):
        time.import
        btn1=Button()
        btn1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.Function2(self)
        return

    def Function2(self):
        btn2=Button(bg='black')
        btn2.grid(row=1,column=1)
        return
```

Comment: Add delay (time.sleep()) inside the body of the second function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a GUI interface, calling `time.sleep` makes the whole process wait, so the application appears to freeze. With Tk in Python, a way to do is to use the Tk `after` method on a window or frame, and then call a function that makes the necessary change to your Button. There are examples of how to do this at [How to create a timer using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/how-to-create-a-timer-using-tkinter)

Comment: after worked, but only after I figured out I forgot to do self.root.mainloop() in every function

Answer (score 0):

Use `time.sleep` to pause program execution for a certain amount of time. If you wanted to pause for 1 second after calling `CreateInterface`, change it to this:

```
def CreateInterface(self):
        btn1=Button()
        btn1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.Function2(self)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Don't forget to `import time` when you do this.

Comment: No, I want to call CreateInterface the moment I click start, then 1 second passes and then Function2() is called; I want a blank button to stay for a second after the start button is clicked and then a black button replace it. The problem is that after I click start, a second passes without creating interface, and then a black button is immediately spawned. In real program, I have a much bigger frame than one button, so I am sure it isn't a problem of not creating a blank button at all.

Comment: @RobiCvjetinović then just put `time.sleep` in a different function.