# Clicks-per-second tester counts clicks even during sleep period

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, sleep

I want to write a click speed tester which worked fine at first. Now I want you to have a certain time window in which you can click, then the final results are displayed. It will wait 2 seconds and then it should start all over again.

The problem is that when it starts over again, it also counts the clicks you performed in the 2-second pause. How can I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from time import sleep
import time
from pynput import mouse
import os

CPSL=0
CPSR=0
Time=5
mode="Time"#oneDrack, Time, Double
startTime=0
nowTime=0
CPSLT=0
CPSRT=0
double=0
buttosPressed=0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global CPSL, CPSR, mode, startTime, nowTime, double, Time, buttosPressed
    if (str(button) == "Button.left" and pressed):
        buttosPressed="CPSL"
        CPSL+=1
    if (str(button) == "Button.right" and pressed):
        buttosPressed="CPSR"
        CPSR+=1
    if (mode == "Time"):
        if (pressed):
            if double==0:
                print("start")
                CPSR=0
                CPSL=0
                if (buttosPressed=="CPSL"): CPSL=1
                else: CPSL=0
                if (buttosPressed=="CPSR"): CPSR=1
                else: CPSR=0
                print(CPSL, end=" ")
                print(CPSR)
                double=1
                startTime=time.time()
            else:
                nowTime=time.time()
                difTime=nowTime - startTime
                if (difTime < Time):
                    print(CPSL, end=" ")
                    print(CPSR)
                else:
                    if (buttosPressed=="CPSL"): CPSL-=1
                    if (buttosPressed=="CPSR"): CPSR-=1
                    print("Finaly")
                    print(CPSL, end=" ")
                    print(CPSR)
                    sleep (2.5)
                    double=0
with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click
) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I guess `sleep` isn't the right thing to do here. What about a timer instead that starts and stops measuring sessions?

Comment: I don't understand how should I make such a timer?

Comment: maybe this will help you understand the tkinter option https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401181/2932052

Comment: ok i'm going to take a look THX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `sleep` is that it doesn't prevent events from happening but it disables event handling in your program. That's why you observe a lot of events after each sleep period.

As mentioned in my comment, tkinter is a valid option to build such a click counter, and it also brings the benefit to come along with python, so no need for 3rd party packages. The change between the stages *counting* and *displaying* is done by a sort of "timer". Actually, it's a timed function call by using the [`after`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method which is universal for all widgets.

So this could be a good starting point for you click-rate counter program:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.counting = False;
        self.clicks = 0
        self.label = tk.Label(text="", )
        self.label.bind('<Button-1>', self.label_click_left)
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_clock()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def label_click_left(self, event):
        if self.counting:
            self.clicks += 1
            
    def update_clock(self):
        if self.counting:
            self.label.configure(text='counting...')
        else:
            self.label.configure(text=f'{(self.clicks/2):.2f} CPS')
        self.counting = not self.counting
        self.root.after(2000, self.update_clock)

app=App()
```