# Animate Text in Tkinter Label Widget (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to animate a label text in tkinter (python). for that purpose, i am using time.sleep() method for updating 1 character in Label widget after a second but it is not updating Label widget instantly rather it is updating label at once at the end of timer. How could i fix this?. Here is my code:-

```py
from tkinter import *
import time


global a



def update(a):
    txt = 'Sample Text'
    mylabel.configure(text=txt[0:a])
    
def timer():
    global a
    a = 0
    lenth = len('Sample Text')
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        # Do other stuff, it won't be blocked
        time.sleep(0.1)

        # When 1 sec or more has elapsed...
        if time.time() - start > 1:
            start = time.time()
            a = a + 1

            # This will be updated once per second
            print("{} counter".format(a))
            update(a)
            # Count up to the lenth of text, ending loop
            if a > lenth:
                break

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

mylabel = Label(root, text="S", font=('Bell', 36, 'bold'))
mylabel.pack(pady=5)

root.after(3000, timer)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use an asynchronous method, Thread.

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep()`, use `.after()` to update the label periodically. It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: There are already some similar questions on StackOverflow, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/how-can-i-schedule-updates-f-e-to-update-a-clock-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use loop and `time.sleep()` in the main thread of a tkinter application because it will block the tkinter `mainloop()` from updating widgets until the loop exits. That is why you can only see the result after the loop completes.

Use `.after()` instead:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry('300x300')

txt = 'Sample Text'

lbl = tk.Label(root, font='Bell 36 bold', width=len(txt))
lbl.pack(pady=5)

def animate_label(text, n=0):
    if n < len(text)-1:
        # not complete yet, schedule next run one second later
        lbl.after(1000, animate_label, text, n+1)
    # update the text of the label
    lbl['text'] = text[:n+1]

# start the "after loop" one second later
root.after(1000, animate_label, txt)
root.mainloop()
```