# Run certain code every n seconds

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way to, for example, print `Hello World!` every n seconds?
For example, the program would go through whatever code I had, then once it had been 5 seconds (with `time.sleep()`) it would execute that code. I would be using this to update a file though, not print Hello World.

For example:

```
startrepeat("print('Hello World')", .01) # Repeats print('Hello World') ever .01 seconds

for i in range(5):
    print(i)

>> Hello World!
>> 0
>> 1
>> 2
>> Hello World!
>> 3
>> Hello World!
>> 4
```

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/474528/4279)

Comment: @jfs this question is a little different to your link, as this question is wanting to run code _asynchronously_ to the main code execution.

Comment: @101: I don't know whether you see it, but I haven't closed neither of the questions. btw, [RepeatedTimer](btw,https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317060/4279) seems answers the current question. Here's [a variant that doesn't start a new thread on each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498708/4279) or  [asyncio-based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279) if you need one.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()

# continue with the rest of your code
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: This isn't working either - it will just print hello world then do whatever code I put after it, without repeating itself.

Comment: you can probably create a method SetAlarm which takes all require arguments to execute the function and this method will set threading.Timer and just return, I mean like this..........
timer = threading.Timer(wait, fn, args, kwargs)             you can also use mx DateTime to calculate the time interval using DateTime.RelativeDateTime(days=interval),
timer.start()

Comment: @Zonda, oops, forgot to start the thread -- editing now to fix, sorry.

Comment: OK, fixed, note that you may also want to set the thread made by `Timer` as a `daemon` in case you want to interrupt the program cleanly by just finishing the main thread -- in that case you'd better set `t = threading.Timer` &c, then `t.daemon = True`, and only then `t.start()` right before the `print "Hello, World!"`.

Comment: @shah, yes, the idea can be wrapped in a more general function (not necessarily a method -- personally, if I needed that, I'd make it a decorator-style nested function), though the _repeated_ calls to `threading.Timer` are a must, be they directly in the function that must repeat, or a smart general wrapper for it.  `mx.DateTime` is pretty obsolete since Python's standard library gained module `datetime` (many years ago) and wouldn't help anyway for the "repeat every 5 seconds" spec the OP posed in their question.

Comment: This seems not to resolve the question at all...  it does not repeat every second.

Comment: @YanKingYin: try to run it. It does repeat. `printit` schedules itself.

Comment: It is important to understand that this timer fires only once (unlike other known timers that fire repeatedly). Therefore it has to restart itself every 5 seconds.

Comment: It is printing the thing twice . I think the function is being called twice.

Comment: How would you prevent multiple instances of this starting? For example if you scheduled something to run every 5 seconds but it took 10 seconds to complete?

Comment: Finally figured out this unclear piece of code! The last line is not a method definition and it is not inside printit. It is a call to the printit method from somewhere else. And if you don't add t.daemon = True as suggested, then the IDE crashes.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm accustomed to doing this in JavaScript which is quite different. Excellent answer (+1) ;)

Comment: This is so helpful!

Comment: wouldn't this eventually hit the recursive function limit?

Comment: How do I stop it?

Comment: This code it totally wrong, It not only cause "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" but also will not provide a way to stop it.  As some answer bellow the way to go is using a scheduler

Comment: @AbelSurace There is no recursion. But if the runtime of the function exceeds the interval you may end up with something similar to a fork bomb.

Comment: @moooeeeep : You are calling  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!" from within def prinit() function.. I don't know how you call a function that calls it self.. in my side of the world we call it recursive.

Comment: @AbelSurace Calling the function recursively is not the same as launching a new thread to run the function. The first adds to the recursion depth of the current thread and the other doesn't.

Comment: @DakshShah: you don't, as start/stop control was not requested by the OP. For such control, see my answer below.

Comment: @AbelSurace: It has no recursion because it launches _in another thread_ and `printit()` continues to the end. Your side of the world is a single-threaded one. Welcome to the multi-threading side :-)

Comment: Note that this code doesn't actually address the question: this runs a function, once. Where's the rest of the code that effects the interval call (without blocking the main thread, and without making new threads over and over?)

Answer (score 158):

My humble take on the subject, a generalization of [Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393759/624066), with start() and stop() control:

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer     = None
        self.interval   = interval
        self.function   = function
        self.args       = args
        self.kwargs     = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
    
    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    
    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True
    
    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False
```

Usage:

```
from time import sleep

def hello(name):
    print "Hello %s!" % name

print "starting..."
rt = RepeatedTimer(1, hello, "World") # it auto-starts, no need of rt.start()
try:
    sleep(5) # your long-running job goes here...
finally:
    rt.stop() # better in a try/finally block to make sure the program ends!
```

Features:

- Standard library only, no external dependencies
- `start()` and `stop()` are safe to call multiple times even if the timer has already started/stopped
- function to be called can have positional and named arguments
- You can change `interval` anytime, it will be effective after next run. Same for `args`, `kwargs` and even `function`!

Comment: All I need is the `sleep()` function. Thank you.

Comment: @JossieCalderon: The `sleep()` function is in the `time` module from Python's Standard Library, no need of any additional code to use it besides the `import`. But please note this is a one-time blocking call, not a repeated multi-threaded timer as the OP requested. Basically, `sleep()` is just a pause, not a timer.

Comment: @MestreLion Yep - it only runs when it's called.

Comment: This is nice, but note that it doesn't run the job every n seconds. Instead, it runs a n-second timer, then quickly starts another n-second timer... but there is a delay before the next timer starts. So this doesn't fire precisely every n seconds; rather, it drifts, with a bit more than n seconds between jobs. A 1 second timer running a job to print the current time yields:

starting...
16:07:42.017682
16:07:43.023215
16:07:44.023626

etc.

Comment: Yes, @eraoul , it does drift as there is no straightforward way to set a truly *recurring* timer using Python's Standard Library, so I "chained" several one-time timers to simulate it. The drift, however, was 5ms on first run and 0.4ms on the following, so it would take approximately somewhere from 200 to 2500 runs to drift a whole second, which might or might not be significant for you. For more accuracy over thousands of runs one could either calculate the next run based on the RTC or use an external tool such as `cron`

Comment: Thank you for this. I added `self._timer.daemon = True` to handle shutdowns better and moved the function call right after `self._timer.start()` to have it run immediately.

Comment: what should I do If I want to stop the function after 30 mins.

Comment: @Sarthak: stop the timer you say? You could either add some logic to the called function to check elapsed time (comparing current time with a global, previously saved start time) _or_ create another 30-minute timer, both approaches would disable the repeated timer (and also itself in case of the second timer)

Comment: I did run this timer with a interval of 0.1 seconds, thus each time a thread new gets with a new timer. Used self._timer.daemon = True and return to improve memory allocation over time .

`def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = threading.Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.daemon = True
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True
        return  #improves ability to be garbage collected`

Comment: Note that this code makes new threads over and over, and will quite happily error out in a way that can't be caught.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: actually, it will make a _single_ thread over and over, so at any given time you'd have at most 2 threads: the main one and the timer. And yes, handling errors between threads is tricky and out of the scope for a simple std lib class like this. But one could (and should) always handle exceptions in the called funcion (in my example, `hello()`

Answer (score 34):

Save yourself a schizophrenic episode and use the [Advanced Python scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/):

The code is so simple:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

def some_job():
    print "Every 10 seconds"

sched.add_interval_job(some_job, seconds = 10)

....
sched.shutdown()
```

Comment: First of all, the submodule is called 'schedulers', with an 's'. And there is no class Scheduler in there. Maybe BackgroundScheduler? Anyway, this answer is incomplete and does not work.

Comment: It's been a while, I guess I pasted the code from the web user manual.  The above code is now corrected (still not tested, but it comes from my own working code and I am using it constantly).
PS:  maybe we are looking at different versions / modules?  I'm sure my line is "from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler" with capital S and not plural.

Comment: @MadsSkjern: I see that [2.1 branch has `apscheduler.scheduler` (no `s`) module](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/11c5c1e7b8c33205293168e044d90b7f2c84a21b/apscheduler/?at=2.1). The current branch 3 does not.

Comment: Anyone looking at this answer now (Nov 2014) should be aware that this, while a good answer, is all wrong. The above comments discuss this. To add a job in the current version the code would read `sched.add_job(some_job, 'interval', seconds = 10)`. Look at the [documentation](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/#)

Answer (score 30):

```
def update():
    import time
    while True:
        print 'Hello World!'
        time.sleep(5)
```

That'll run as a function. The `while True:` makes it run forever. You can always take it out of the function if you need.

Comment: Doesn't work; it just runs forever and I cant do anything else while it is.

Comment: What other things do you want to be doing at the same time?

Comment: Well this just runs in a loop. You didn't specify in the question that you'd be doing something else in the meantime so I assumed that's what you need.

Comment: Note: This will not _quite_ run every 5 seconds. It will run every `5 + N` seconds, where `N` is the time it takes to execute the time between `while True:` and `time.sleep(5)`. While this is negligible for `print 'Hellow World!'` in comparison to 5 whole seconds, it may be nontrivial for other scenarios. I should note that using threads won't quite get it to 5 seconds exactly either, but it will be closer.

Comment: I know I'm like 9 years too late, but this isn't a valid solution, he specifically said `...the program would go through whatever code I had, then once it had been 5 seconds...`.

Comment: @avacariu Thanks for your help. This simple snippet of code saved my day.

Comment: this keeps GIL locked while the fuction "executes" the sleep command , making python not available for other tasks.

Comment: then you need to offload to this function to a thread,  you can also use a subprocess as well that doesn't wait for the return

Answer (score 28):

Here is a simple example compatible with [APScheduler 3.00+](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io):

```
# note that there are many other schedulers available
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

def some_job():
    print('Every 10 seconds')

# seconds can be replaced with minutes, hours, or days
sched.add_job(some_job, 'interval', seconds=10)
sched.start()

...

sched.shutdown()
```

Alternatively, you can use the following. Unlike many of the alternatives, this timer will execute the desired code every *n* seconds exactly (irrespective of the time it takes for the code to execute). So this is a great option if you cannot afford any drift.

```
import time
from threading import Event, Thread

class RepeatedTimer:

    """Repeat `function` every `interval` seconds."""

    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.start = time.time()
        self.event = Event()
        self.thread = Thread(target=self._target)
        self.thread.start()

    def _target(self):
        while not self.event.wait(self._time):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    @property
    def _time(self):
        return self.interval - ((time.time() - self.start) % self.interval)

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()
        self.thread.join()


# start timer
timer = RepeatedTimer(10, print, 'Hello world')

# stop timer
timer.stop()
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a version that doesn't create a new thread every `n` seconds:

```
from threading import Event, Thread

def call_repeatedly(interval, func, *args):
    stopped = Event()
    def loop():
        while not stopped.wait(interval): # the first call is in `interval` secs
            func(*args)
    Thread(target=loop).start()    
    return stopped.set
```

The event is used to stop the repetitions:

```
cancel_future_calls = call_repeatedly(5, print, "Hello, World")
# do something else here...
cancel_future_calls() # stop future calls
```

See [Improve current implementation of a setInterval python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22498038/4279)

Comment: It's worth noting that while this does allow something else to run while waiting for `func` to run again, this solution does not account for how long it takes `func` itself to run.  So this solution waits `n` seconds *between* runs, as opposed to running every `n` seconds.  Other solutions above at least come much closer to running every `n` seconds, though this solution has its advantages too.

Comment: @Mike: yes. If you follow the link; you see that it is mentioned explicitly and the corresponding solution is suggested. It depends on a specific case what solution is preferable.

Comment: it would be very nice if you could explain if the print function is called in the main thread. If yes, would the `do something else` code be run in another thread?

Comment: @toing_toing look at the code: "print" function is passed as "func" parameter to "call_repeatedly". "func" is called inside "loop" that is executed in another thread (look at `Thread(target=loop)`). In short: no, "print" function is not called in the main thread here.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a separate thread whose sole duty is to count for 5 seconds, update the file, repeat. You wouldn't want this separate thread to interfere with your main thread.