# changing global variable with thread in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a script updating a global variable every 10 seconds.  For simplicity let's just increment `q` once teach time

```python
import time, threading

q = 0
def f(q):
    # get asset position every 10 seconds:
    q += 1
    print q

    # call f() again in 10 seconds
    threading.Timer(10, f).start()


# start calling f now and every 10 sec thereafter
f(q)
```

Instead python says:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'q' referenced before assignment
```

What is the correct way to change the variable `q`?

---

this example uses threading, doesn't update any values.
[Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds)

Comment: Put `global q` at the top of the `f` function.

Comment: @dano I didn't know you could do that in Python.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare q as a global. `q += 1` confuses the interpreter otherwise.

```
import threading

q = 0
def f():
    global q
    q += 1
    print q
    threading.Timer(10, f).start()

f()
```