# Run certain code after x seconds, every n seconds in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way to, for example, print Hello World! every n seconds after x seconds? Looking at this:
[Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds), I know how to run a code every n seconds. But I would like to run certain code after x seconds every n seconds.

Need some guidance on how to do this.

Key condition: The program should not lag or sleep. The certain code I am referring to is a function call.

Comment: Your linked answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3393759/341744 calls the function `printit` every 5 seconds, without blocking the rest of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import threading
import time

def printit():
  threading.Timer(n, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

threading.Timer(x, printit)
```

Comment: I don't think the code snippet stuff works with Python.

Comment: I see that now :/ very sad.

Comment: time.sleep makes my whole program wait before the rest of the code works

Comment: So your wanting a non blocking wait?

Comment: @ghostbust555 you forgot to add .start() after the initial Timer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do something like (to run it after 5 seconds, and it'll run every 10 seconds):

```
import time

time.sleep(5)

while True:
    your code
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: instead of time.sleep, mine is a function. so while true, it will be running all the time..

Comment: time.sleep makes my whole program wait.. before the while true occurs.

Answer (score 0):

### A: Yes, both ways are possible

For a given task, give a try to use **`Tkinter`** internal scheduling, **which does not block.**

Key methods are:

```
 .after( n_msec_from_now, aScheduledFuncCALL )  # to plan a call not before n_msec-s
 .after_idle(             aScheduledFuncCALL )  # to plan a call after GUI gets <idle>
```

more smart options available

```
import Tkinter as tk

def RunCertainCodeCALL():
    #a CertainCode
    root.after( x * 1000, RunCertainCodeCALL )  # .SET for next round of schedulling

root = tk.Tk()
root.after( x * 1000, RunCertainCodeCALL )      # .SET for 1-st round of schedulling
root.mainloop()                                 # .GUI mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no indication that the OP is using `Tkinter`, is there?

Comment: Dano, how does your question relate to the solution? If you are familiar with Tkinter module internals, you are sure to know, that the benefits of .mainloop() scheduler meet the OP interest. If not, kindly accept there are more ways to reach the OP Task Solution, aren't there?

Comment: Using a `Tkinter`-based solution would really only make sense if the OP's application is already built around the `Tkinter` mainloop. I don't think that refactoring to make the entire program work within the confines of the mainloop makes sense when something based on `threading.Timer` is available.

Comment: Right, what Tkinter adds to the solution is the scheduling flexibility & elasticity, which threading.Timer() lacks. The code may adapt scheduling delays accordingly upon the application / GUI workloads, which has an immense value in soft-real-time systems.

Comment: I'm not sure what flexibility you're gaining with `after` that isn't possible with `Timer`. Your `after`-based solution looks a whole lot like the `Timer`-based solution, except yours revolves around an event loop instead of threads. In both cases you can adjust the schedule as you go. Can you clarify what you mean? I just don't think any event-loop based solution - asyncio.call_later`, `gobject.timeout_add`, etc. - makes sense here unless you're using that framework to begin with.

Comment: Yes, sure, dano, flexibility was meant to be able to adapt and either hard-schedule or soft-schedule tasks, based on the workload and application  context. AFAIK `threading.Timer()` does not allow for any kind of elastic, relaxed scheduling alike `.after_idle()` or `.update_idletasks()` and other context-aware deferred scheduling options alike `.wait_visibility()` or `.wait_variable()` constructs, which make the overall design capable of smarter, elastic non-blocking scheduling and to some extents self-controlled prioritisation possible.