# Is there a way to let generator (yield) return data every 0.1 second (Python)?

Tags: python, generator

I am developing a server-based data acquisition application. I want the server to read data from file (to simulate real data stream) every 0.01 second. Every it reads a chunk of data from the file. So I am using a generator to read data by chunks. Then I am think about using some sort of timer to control how often to the generator returns data. I have tried the RepeatedTimer mentioned in this post, but it didn't work. Any help on this?

Just a simple generator for your information.

```
def generator():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count = count + 1
        yield count
```

The RepeatedTimer module is mentioned here (the 3rd answer): [Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds)

This is how I called the RepeatedTimer. When running the code, there was no response.

```
count = RepeatedTimer(0.01, generator)
print count
```

Comment: Because you don't iterate over a generator by calling the generator function repeatedly...

Comment: Oh yeah, that's why. Thank you. do you have any thought on how to let generator return a value every 0.01 second?

Comment: You could just add a `time.sleep(0.01)` to your loop.