# Timer event Python video stream handling

Tags: python, opencv, video, timer

I want to use opencv (cv2) in python to open a camera and take a frame every 1 second (in C++ or C# I can use a timer event). I will then process something while other frames are still showing.

Anyone knows how?

Comment: You can do the same thing in python as well. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/474543/4962554) answer should be useful. You could also use [threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393759/4962554) as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)