# Print Updated Variable using Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to print an updated value and store it in a CSV file. Im using threading and the print would be every 1 second, however after every second that ellapses its the same value that is printed. Can someone help?

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import threading
import time

localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()))



url = 'api'

uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read().decode()

js =json.loads(data)


def last_price():
  threading.Timer(1.0, last_price).start()
  print(js['last'])
  print(localtime)


last_price()
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `js` is currently evaluated only once. If you want to query the API every second, move the query code inside the function being executed by the timer:

```
url = 'api'

def last_price():
    localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()))
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read().decode()
    js = json.loads(data)
    print(js['last'])
    print(localtime)
    threading.Timer(1.0, last_price).start()

last_price()
```

Comment: This is a good way of doing it, but since it takes some time for Python to execute all the code inside the function, it will technically be a bit more than a minute... (which I wouldn't say is an issue)

Comment: thank you, realized this myself after walking away and thinking about it for a second. Still a noob here...thx!

Comment: @ArthurSpoon you're correct, but if you fire the timer at the beginning you're risking spawning many threads if, for example, the API is unresponsive and blocks you for a long time. Handling that will be an unnecessary overhead if millisecond precision is not of high priority.

Comment: I was more making a comment about `Thread` in general doing that (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384065/is-there-a-way-to-stop-timer-creep/45384212#45384212) for example). But as I said, I don't think it's an issue here, I just wanted to make a precision :)