# Update RSS feed every 2 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, timer, feedparser

I've searched pretty everywhere so that's why I'm asking here.
My program shows a parsed RSS feed (news), that looks like this in the end:

```
feedShow = feed['entries'][0]['title']
```

Now, this `feedShow` element is the text displayed later by a Label. The `0` in the code line determines which news title to display. I'd like to change that every 2 minutes to +1.
How do I do that? I'd have known in a more basic situation but that's in the middle of the code. As my clock, I use

```
import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would suggest you take a look at 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds/13151299
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Comment: I don't see why this should be duplicate to the question you have linked. My main question is not how to execute the program every 2 minutes, but mainly how to change the 0. Could you please explain how that's related? I'm kind of noobish here
(i have no intent of sounding rude)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this. Code will update the `self.headlineIndex` every X seconds (currently set to 1 second). The headline is grabbed using `headline = feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']`. Notice the `self.headlineIndex` inside the square braces rather than a number like zero.

```
    try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

"""Some dummy data in the same format as OP"""
feed = {'entries': [{'title':"US Pres. incompetent"},
                    {'title':"Sport happened"},
                    {'title':"Politican Corrupt"}]
        }

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.txtHeadline = tk.StringVar()
        self.headline = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.txtHeadline)
        self.headline.grid()

        self.headlineIndex = 0

        self.updateHeadline()

    def updateHeadline(self):
        try:
            headline = feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']
        except IndexError:
            """This will happen if we go beyond the end of the list of entries"""
            self.headlineIndex = 0
            headline = feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']

        self.txtHeadline.set(headline)
        self.headlineIndex += 1
        self.after(1000,self.updateHeadline)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you! At least there is someone who answers the questions instead of downvoting!

Comment: Hey, the program is awesome, but I've stumbled across a really noobish and probably facepalming. I'm working with a full screen window, and use labels for everything. I cannot find a way to move your "self.headline" in the middle. The .place(coordinates) isn't working, and modifying the .grid() to .grid(rows&columns) doesn't result in anything either

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to mix grid/pack/place layout methods. You may have to change my code to only use place throughout. I never use place so I'm not sure.