# How to prevent Python from opening too many files while threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I need to run a specific function every second. I have searched for a solution and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393759/9982372):

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

It seems to be the code I have been searching for. But after running those lines of code for 20 Minutes I have got following error message:

> Exception in thread Thread-1896: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1180, in run File
>   "/home/pi/scanner/api/brightness.py", line 37, in adjust_brightness
>   File "/home/pi/scanner/api/brightness.py", line 14, in get_brightness
>   OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

It seems that every time the function is called a new thread starts. Is there a way to stop the previous thread before the new one gets generated? Or are there other solutions where this doesn't happen?

Comment: Exactly what I thought. How can my problem be better solved?

Comment: You said "every time the function is called a new thread starts". Indeed! It's a simple auto-repeating timer. A program that uses it is only supposed to call it once, and then it restarts itself every 5 seconds. So you will cause chaos if you try to call it yourself multiple times. Maybe take a look at some of the other solutions on that page, like MestreLion's.