# How to write data to a file every 10 seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm a JS dev trying to learn a bit of Python while working on a Raspberry-Pi3 project that reads data from a Bluetooth temperature sensor.

I need to write the data to my file.txt every 10 seconds, how could I do that please? I found similar topic here ([Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds) ), but I don't know how to make it work in my current scenario.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import re
import logging
import sys
import time

from btlewrap import available_backends, BluepyBackend, GatttoolBackend, PygattBackend
from mitemp_bt.mitemp_bt_poller import MiTempBtPoller, \
    MI_TEMPERATURE, MI_HUMIDITY, MI_BATTERY

def valid_mitemp_mac(mac, pat=re.compile(r"4C:65:A8:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}")):
    """Check for valid mac adresses."""
    if not pat.match(mac.upper()):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('The MAC address "{}" seems to be in the wrong format'.format(mac))
    return mac

def poll(args):
    """Poll data from the sensor."""
    backend = _get_backend(args)
    poller = MiTempBtPoller(args.mac, backend)
    line1 = "Temperature: {}".format(poller.parameter_value(MI_TEMPERATURE))
    line2 = "Humidity: {}".format(poller.parameter_value(MI_HUMIDITY))
    print("Getting data from Mi Temperature and Humidity Sensor")
    print("FW: {}".format(poller.firmware_version()))
    print("Name: {}".format(poller.name()))
    print("Battery: {}".format(poller.parameter_value(MI_BATTERY)))
    print(line1)
    print(line2)
    f = open('file.txt', 'w')
    f.write("%s \n %s \n" % (line1, line2))
    f.close()

def _get_backend(args):
    """Extract the backend class from the command line arguments."""
    if args.backend == 'gatttool':
        backend = GatttoolBackend
    elif args.backend == 'bluepy':
        backend = BluepyBackend
    elif args.backend == 'pygatt':
        backend = PygattBackend
    else:
        raise Exception('unknown backend: {}'.format(args.backend))
    return backend


def list_backends(_):
    """List all available backends."""
    backends = [b.__name__ for b in available_backends()]
    print('\n'.join(backends))

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--backend', choices=['gatttool', 'bluepy', 'pygatt'], default='gatttool')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_const', const=True)
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', )

    parser_poll = subparsers.add_parser('poll', help='poll data from a sensor')
    parser_poll.add_argument('mac', type=valid_mitemp_mac)
    parser_poll.set_defaults(func=poll)

    parser_scan = subparsers.add_parser('backends', help='list the available backends')
    parser_scan.set_defaults(func=list_backends)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.verbose:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    if not hasattr(args, "func"):
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)

    args.func(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Where is your specific problem?

Comment: @PatrickArtner the poll function in where i'm writing the data to the file, but it's only doing it once and then program ends. I would like to keep it running every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `time` module to pause the program for 10 seconds on each iteration;

```
from time import sleep

def func(n):
    print(n+1)

for i in range(5):
    func(i)
    sleep(10)

>1
>2
>3
>4
>5

# (every 10 seconds)
```

However this will block the rest of the program running, although a simple multi-threading script to call the writing function would suffice.

And in relation to the code you are using, insert the `sleep` call within the `poll` function and wrap what you have there. If you want to loop the program 10 times then;

```
def poll(args):
    """Poll data from the sensor."""
    for _ in range(10):
        # code things
        f = open('file.txt', 'a') # << Use append here or you will keep overwriting file contents
        f.write('hello')
        f.close()
        sleep(10)
```

Or if you want it to run forever until you `KeyboardInterrupt` or exit somehow:

```
def poll(args):
    """Poll data from the sensor."""
    while True:
        # code things
        f = open('file.txt', 'a') # << Use append here or you will keep overwriting file contents
        f.write('hello')
        f.close()
        sleep(10)
```

Comment: I added this before/after the poll function, and it seems to ignore the rest of my code. It's only doing print1,2,3.. How can i use it to also make use of the `poll` function?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes, but for the moment i'm fine with that. I will just use that file and pick-up from there using Node (which i know better for now). I couldn't find any node package that would read the sensor, so i'm forced to use python.

Comment: I stripped the code out and just leaving the 'example'

Comment: I will use my node server to read whatever is in that file at a particular time and that will be my data.

Comment: Matt B. i will use with you solution for now, since it's easier to use and closer to my level. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. you need some kind of loop that polls your sensor - I do not see one glancing over your code. You got while and for loops in JS as well - look them up in http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial if you are unsure about the syntax.
2. store the time you wrote to a variable , sleep a bit poll the next value, check if 10s passed, write if, else not. (or simply sleep 10s between polls if you do not want intermediate values printed

Readup about loops:

- [*for* statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)
- [looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

---

```
import time

def poll():
    return time.time(), 42

last_write = None    # when did we record to file last?

# loop for as long as you want - while True would loop endlessly
for _ in range(7):
    t,c = poll()     # call poll() to get time and temperature from mocked data reader

    # check if enough time has passed
    if last_write is None or (t-last_write) > 2:  # check if new reading needed
        with open("t.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(f"{t}    {c}\n")
        last_write=t
        print("in file ", t,c)            
    else:
        print("just output ", t,c)
    time.sleep(0.7)                               # sleep some
```

Output:

```
in file  1552978725.5224085 42                # ...25.5
just output  1552978726.2232893 42            # ...26.2  - not 2s passed 
just output  1552978726.9241226 42            # ...26.9  - not 2s passed
in file  1552978727.6249442 42                # ...27.6  - 2.1s passed 
just output  1552978728.3259027 42            # ...28.3  - not 2s passed
just output  1552978729.0267787 42            # ...29.0  - not 2s passed 
in file  1552978729.7275977 42                # ...29.7  - 2.1s passed
```

More remarks:

- use `with open(filename,mode) as f:` and scope the file opeations below it - it will autoclose your file after scope and handle exceptions by closing the filehandle as well.
- Using mode "w" will truncate the file before writing to it - you might want to use append instead: [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)