# How does threading.Timer avoid recursion in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion, timer

I found a code snippet in stackoverflow ([Run certain code every n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds)) that runs a function after every n seconds.

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

I tried to do the same with my code and of course I got *RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object*

```
import time

def call_f_after_n_secs(f, n):
    time.sleep(n)
    f()

def my_fun():
    print("my_fun")
    call_f_after_n_secs(my_fun, 0.01)

my_fun()
```

My question is, how does threading.Timer avoid maximum recursion depth ? I mean (except from the part of threading that "detaches" the code from the main flow of the program) how does Timer work internally and calls printit() without making recursive calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "except from the part of threading that "detaches" the code from the
>   main flow of the program"

You can't understand it without that part. The original setup doesn't introduce recursion in the first place because `printit()` gets called in *another* thread. Every thread has its own stack and the first thread never adds another call to `printit()` to it. The original thread just initializes a new `Thread`-object and the new thread itself calls `printit()` after it bootstraps.