# python execute function every n seconds wait for completion

Tags: python, process, execution, schedule, periodicity

I want to execute FUNCTION periodically every 60 seconds, but I don't want to execute FUNCTION again IF the previous run has not completed yet. If the previous run completes in e.g. 120s then I want to execute a new FUNCTION call straight away. If previous run completed in e.g. 10s then I want to wait 50s before I execute a new FUNCTION call.

Please see my implementation below.

Can I achieve it with e.g. subprocess.run or some timeloop library so that the implementation would be much cleaner?

```
import time


def hello(x):
    # some logic here
    # execution could take any time between e.g. <10s, 120s>


def main(ii):
    while True:
        start = int(time.time())

        try:
            val = next(ii)
        except StopIteration as ex:
            return None

        else:
            hello(val)

            run_time_diff = int(time.time()) - start

            if run_time_diff < 60:
                time.sleep(60 - run_time_diff)


ii = iter(list[[...],[...],...[...]])
main(ii=ii)
```

Comment: There is no need for the low-level `iter` and `next`. Just use a plain `for` loop, it is much more cleaner. I think your scheduler with runtime calculation is OK, except the `int()` for the timestamps introduces rounding errors.

Comment: I just want to operate on the iterator due to memory efficiency.

Comment: Did you check [run-certain-code-every-n-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds) ?

Comment: I saw it and I could not see a solution there to handle the drift.

Comment: @NullByte A for-loop uses an iterator internally, no need to duplicate its functionality. Passing a list as an argument does not decrease memory efficency, the list (or any other object) will NOT be copied.

Comment: is it not the case that I hold a variable with list as a value in a memory and I keep the whole list in memory while I iterate over it? If I create iterator out of it then the memory usage drops? hmm although I assume I still hold reference to the original list...so you may be right. Am I assuming correctly?

Comment: @NullByte You can save memory with iterators only if you generate the list item by item or so. If the list is given, the iterator is just a moving index existing in addition to the original list.

Answer (score 0):

maybe apsheduler could help you. But if your job wil run more then waiting time, it could be skipped. In this case you can increase number of workers.

```
import datetime
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def some_job():
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.utcnow()}: Every 10 seconds")


job = scheduler.add_job(some_job, 'interval', seconds=10, max_instances=1)

scheduler.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
finally:
    scheduler.shutdown()
```