# Change a variable over time

Tags: python, variables, time, pygame, seconds

I’m kind of new to python, I’m trying to make a little game in pygame, in which I have a “hunger bar” which go down over time, I was trying to look for a module or function that every x seconds change the variable “hunger” but each one that I have found stop all the code untill the clock runs out. Anyone has an idea of how can I get this to work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds ?

Answer (score 3):

You are in the ideal situation to use the python's `threading` module.
You can spawn a child thread which runs continuously in background and decrement the `hunger` variable by certain value after the specified intervals.

**For Example:**

```
import time
import threading

hunger = 100
def hungerstrike():
    global hunger
    while True:
        hunger -= 1
        time.sleep(2) # sleep for 2 seconds

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=hungerstrike) # start a child thread
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    # TODO: Do other work
    time.sleep(6)
    print("After 6 seconds, the value of hunger is:", hunger)
```

**Output of `main()`:**

```
After 6 seconds, the value of hunger is: 97
```

Comment: do you have any web page or video where I can learn how this code works? Or could you please explain me ?

Comment: @AbrahamEsquivelth You can search on internet (or youtube) there are lots of tutorials on using `threading` module. For starters you can refer `https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/` or you can looks into official python docs.