# My thread runs every 10 secs but sometimes the function takes longer to run. How do I make the timer wait until the function executes?

Tags: python

My threading is set up exactly like the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds/17492865). Except that my function is more complex than a print.

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(10.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

The function takes about 6 seconds to run. On rare occasions, it takes 12-13 seconds to run. Without incurring opportunity costs by extending the wait time, how do I make this timer wait until the function runs?

Comment: why is it in a thread at all if you want to wait until the code finishes before continuing? why not just have it in a loop?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I see what you mean but my function is a bit complicated but one aspect is the data it pulls relies on timing. I find threading to suits my needs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threading.Timer(10.0, printit).start()`

Is just a thread

you can capture it

```
def printit():
    thread = threading.Timer(10.0, printit)
    thread.start()
    # ... some stuff or something
    thread.join() # wait for thread to finish ?
```

is maybe one way you could ... but why not just skip the timer and do it at the end? or really why not just put it in a loop?

```
def printit():

    # ... some stuff or something
    threading.Thread(target=printit).start() # now you dont need to worry about it
```

but i really dont understand why you are not just using a loop ... this seems like it adds complexity without actually achieving anything useful for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll be right back. Testing the code.

Comment: Thanks Joran. I can confirm that both codes work. I actually went with your second suggestion as the first raised more issues. With my code, I just added a few time.sleep() to make it work with putting a timer at the end.