# execute function every x number of secods python

Tags: python, pygame

I came across this thread when I was looking for a solution, but it doesn't quite do what I need it to:

[What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

This actually "works" (or at least the first solution does) but it doesn't allow you to do it simultaneously along with the rest of the script.

Basically, I need to execute a function like this:

```
    def functionName():
        print "text"
```

I need this to execute every, say, 100 milliseconds. But I need this while loop to be looping simultaneously:

```
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't this work: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer

```
pygame.init()
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 100)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == USEREVENT + 1:
           functionName()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quite()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Perhaps do you want to share a sample.

Comment: @danihp: I've added a sample copied from the comments in their documentation.

Comment: Yeah I saw that earlier and thought it didn't work. it actually does though. Damn this forum works well...

Comment: I just started python and am dev'ing a game. it's a gorgeous language for intermediate programmers!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making a thread and using the `wait()` function so that it prints after every `wait()` function :) If you need help on threads, please look at the official documentation for help or look/ask for a different question on overflow. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably install you function as a signal handler and use [signal.setitimer](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html?highlight=alarm#signal.setitimer). If you are on Unix, that is... Then there are threads and stuff.