# Pausing game and user input in pygame

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I am currently making a game in Pygame, I have the basic game made as I followed a tutorial however know I want to improve it and make it so that after a certain amount of time (e.g. every 30 seconds or so) the game pauses and the user is asked a question and they must enter the right answer to continue playing the game. I have been looking on-line and experimenting a bit however struggling quite a lot! Here is the relevant code:

```
class question():
    pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect = makeTextObjs('9+1.', BASICFONT, WHITE)
    pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect = makeTextObjs('Press A for 10.', BASICFONT, WHITE)
    pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect = makeTextObjs('Press B for 15.', BASICFONT, WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.key==K_a):
            showTextScreen('Correct answer') # pause until a key press
            lastFallTime = time.time()
            lastMoveDownTime = time.time()
            lastMoveSidewaysTime = time.time()
        else:
            showTextScreen("Wrong")

pygame.time.set_timer(question,1000)
```

I have no idea if this is even going in the right direction at the moment as I can't get it to work because I think I understand the error and that I shouldn't be using a class in the timer, however not sure?

Answer (score 2):

You want this to be a function, not a class. Replace `class` with `def`

The bigger problem is that your use of `set_timer` is incorrect. It is:

```
set_timer(eventid, timems)
```

where `eventid` and `timems` are both integers. `set_timer` puts an event into the event queue at the specified interval, it doesn't call any function. You have to put code in the main loop to check for that `eventid` and then execute the appropriate code.

Example code from [this SO answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9894589/1169797):

```
pygame.init()
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 100)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == USEREVENT + 1:
           functionName()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quite()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I understand why this should be however then I get an error message for the timer. The message is:
`line 524, in <module>
    pygame.time.set_timer(question,1000)
TypeError: an integer is required`

Do know how to fix this so it will work as a timer, and so that I can make this like a quiz? Thanks again!

Comment: Updated my answer for ya.