# Use Python to collect weather data and write to file

Tags: python, weather, collect

I would like your advice/help on this:

Create a python script that:

- Every hour collect the **temperature** (e.g. 29<sup>o</sup>C) and **current condition** (e.g. Clear) from this website: http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/54511.html
- Create a CSV file with three headers:

  - Datetime *(timestamp of data captured)*
  - Current Condition
  - Temperature

Add the data collected from the website into a new line of the CSV file.

Rules:

- The script must  be running on your computer automatically for 5 days.

Do you have some advice? :(

I appreciate your help on this.

I tried this :

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))

setURL = 'http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/54511.html?MR=1'
request = urllib2.Request(setURL)
response = opener.open(request)

url = "http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/54511.html?MR=1"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
page = opener.open(request)

WeatherData = page.read()                            
print WeatherData
```

So it print all the data but I want to print only the :

Datetime *(timestamp of data captured)*
   - Current Condition
   - Temperature

- like I said need advice.like :

  - what should I use to complete this task.
  - How can set the data collect for (days), I don't know..

I don't need the full answer and copy paste, I'm not fool...

I want to UNDERSTAND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weather Underground have posted a [Python sample](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples) to access their API. I think you'd be best off using their code. If you play around with the `parsed_json` variable in the example, you should be able to get what you want.

As for running the program after fixed intervals, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python).

Comment: You don't really need to "learn" JSON per se because it is just a way of representing Python types. parsed_json is actually a Python dictionary, so you can just print it out as is and inspect its contents without "knowing" any JSON.

Comment: ow that's nice ! Thanks !got some issues with location = parsed_json['China']['Beijing'] it say in the prompt, key error.will figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to change the url from '/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json' to something like '/q/CN/Beijing.json'. (Try, but may not be the actual link).

Answer (score 2):

This kind of task is called [Screen scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).  The code I show below just adds a few string-manipulation routines for very basic cleanup, but you can do a much better job with a tool made for screen-scraping, like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))

url = "http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/54511.html?MR=1"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
page = opener.open(request)

# This is one big string
rawdata = page.read()

# This breaks it up into lines
lines_of_data = rawdata.split('\n')

# This is one line in the raw data that looks interesing.  I'm going to
# filter the raw data based on the "og:title" text.
# 
#'<meta name="og:title" content="Beijing, Beijing | 31&deg; | Clear" />

# The "if line.find(" bit is the filter. 
special_lines = [line for line in lines_of_data if line.find('og:title')>-1]
print special_lines

# Now we clean up - this is very crude, but you can improve it with
# exactly what you want to do.
info = special_lines[0].replace('"','').split('content=')[1]
sections = info.split('|')
print sections
```

Output:

```
['\t\t<meta name="og:title" content="Beijing, Beijing | 32&deg; | Clear" />']
['Beijing, Beijing ', ' 32&deg; ', ' Clear />']
```

*Edit:*  By all means, if the particular website offers web services like JSON as in the answer by Xaranke, use that!  Not all websites do though, so Beautiful Soup can still be very useful.