# How to wait for the start of a child process?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, psutil

I execute a process (using Popen) and after a while, this process executes a child process.
What I'm trying to do is wait for the child process to be spawned and then continue executing my script.

The only way that I found, is using psutil and polling until the process has children.

```
process = psutil.Process(subprocess.Popen(command).pid)
while 0 == len(process.children()):
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Is there a better way of doing it than polling on the children? Maybe waiting for some event?

I'm using windows 10 for this.

Comment: Is is an option that the first child writes something on its standard output or output error after spawning its own child? Or use any other way to signal the operation.?

Comment: no any another way. no any special events when one process create another (only kernel mode callback called)

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's possible for the process to do something after spawning the child process. (Like printing something to the standard output)

Comment: @RbMm, but there is an event for adding a process to a Job. The child process could be created suspended and added to a Job that doesn't allow breakaway and which is associated with a Completion Port. Then when the child is resumed and in turn spawns another process, the Job will post a `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS` to the Completion Port, which will contain the PID of the grandchild process. The grandparent process waits for this message via `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`.

Comment: @eryksun - i mean in general case, if specific process special design for notify when he create child - another situation

Comment: @RbMm, this requires no modification to either the child or grandchild process. It's all handled by the Windows Job object.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, you right. in almost all case this will be good solution. if child not try create process detached from job

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment that you can have the process you're lunching write something to STDOUT when it launches its subprocess, you can easily use `Popen.check_output()` to pick up the STDOUT string from your parent process. For example, if your subprocess (the `command`) writes to STDOUT `Subprocess started\n`, you can do it purely through the `subprocess` module as:

```
import subprocess

response = subprocess.check_output(command)
if response.rstrip() == "Subprocess started":
    print("Woo! Our sub-subprocess was started...")
```

However, if your `command` returns multiple outputs, you might have to weed out the ones you're not interested in. You can do that by observing your subprocess' STDOUT for the aforementioned `Subprocess started` string, something like:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:  # a loop to read our subprocess STDOUT
    line = proc.stdout.readline().rstrip()  # read line-by-line
    if line == "Subprocess started":
        print("Woo! Our sub-subprocess was started...")
        break  # no need to read the STDOUT anymore
```

You can also capture STDERR (or pipe it to STDOUT) if you expect to be receiving error messages from your `command` (e.g. cannot start the subprocess or something like that).

Comment: The problem is, that I still have to wait for the output so I still need to poll using time.sleep

Comment: @cydan - you don't need to do anything, until your subprocesses STDOUT line-buffer is filled (so at least one line) all of this will wait for it (`proc.stdout.readline()` is a blocking action). `subprocess.check_output()` is also blocking if your subprocess is expected to write something to its STDOUT only once.

Comment: Rather than overloading standard I/O for this task, you could create an inheritable pipe and pass the handle value as a command-line argument or environment variable. If it's also a Python process, the child can associate the handle as a file descriptor via `msvcrt.open_osfhandle`, after which it can be used with regular Python I/O functions. Or just use the handle directly via WinAPI `WriteFile`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no better solution for this. But you could optimize the process call:

```
process = psutil.Popen(command)
```

> **[Popen class](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#popen-class)**
>
> A more convenient interface to stdlib subprocess.Popen. It starts a sub process and you deal with it exactly as when using subprocess.Popen but in addition it also provides all the methods of psutil.Process class. [...]

Additionally, you could use write your own event with a wait function. Wait is more CPU hungry but it is more responsive. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082268/python-time-sleep-vs-event-wait?answertab=votes#tab-top) for example. But it depends on your python version.

Answer (score 0):

If the first child can write something after spawning its own child, the master script could wait for the first write.

Here is a working example (environment Python 2.7 on Windows):

Python master script:

```
python = r"C:\Python27\python.exe"
script = r"...\foo.py"
deb = time.clock()
child = subprocess.Popen([ python, script], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
cr = child.stdout.read()
fin = time.clock()
print fin-deb, cr
```

Python (simplified) first child:

```
time.sleep(2)  # add a delay
# the child is supposed to be spawned here
print "Done"
sys.stdout.flush()  # flushes stdout so that caller gets it immediately
time.sleep(8)       # just to make the child live a little longer
```

The master script output is:

```
2.12153148707 Done
```

proving that the master script continued after the first sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the child process you can use some synchronization primitive between parent and child, like using a socket or a file, otherwise polling over `children()` in a busy loop is the only thing you can do, just make sure to exit the while loop after a while or your program may end up hanging indefinitely.