# How to monitor a variable in python?

Tags: python, events, subprocess, wait, sleep

I have a simple python flask project in which I need to have a user confirmation before any action can take place.

```
...
#need to confirm from the user before the action takes place. If it is yes, continue with action(), else skip action
#I need to keep monitoring the confirm_var here
action()
...
```

After getting confirmation from the user, I am calling this `confirmation()` function to set the confirm_var using AJAX call.

```
def confirmation()
    #set confirm_var to yes/no depending on user input.
```

So, my question is how to keep monitoring the `confirm_var`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use write your own event with a wait function. Wait is more CPU hungry but it is more responsive. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082268/python-time-sleep-vs-event-wait?answertab=votes#tab-top) for example. But it depends on your python version.