# How to make a time sensitive loop in Python?

Tags: python, time

I want to make a function that prints a statement every 2 minutes. I'm really new to Python and don't fully understand the time library. This is the code I have so far:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 import time                

 now = datetime.now()       

 print now.second           
 print "start"
   while True:
      print "while loop started"
    if (now % 2 == 0):     
       print "Hello"     
    else:                  
       break
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your indentation isn't correct!

Comment: do you mean from a particular time or just every two minutes from when the program starts?

Comment: @AJFarmar sorry, I messed up when putting it in the website!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham every 2 minutes from when the program starts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) here. Since you want a timer for 2 minutes, pass 120 (seconds) as the argument value.

Basically, this translates into something like below:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(120)
    print "Hello"
```

This will print `"Hello"` every 2 minutes.

Note that time.sleep is not entirely accurate, and may be off by a small but arbitrary amount of time because of OS scheduling of other processes etc and execution of the code itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that ```time.sleep()``` is not exact, it can be a few seconds off.

Comment: @pzp Have added a note to that effect, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print "Doing stuff..."
    # do your stuff
    sc.enter(60, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python).