# Python Repeat an algorithm exactly every 5th minute of the hour

Tags: python, loops, time

I need to write a Python  code in order to repeat a trading algorithm exactly every fith minute of the hour. All the solutions that I tried as for example  Sleep() will sum machine time, and this is not what I want.

I need to preserve state between calls, ... I want the algorithm to run exactly every 5 minutes (for example 14:00; 14:05; 14:10; 14:15......). The algorithm (retriving the data and cruncing the numbers) itself takes approximatly 12 seconds to be executed. If the computer is suspended I will skip the iteration.

Comment: related: [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25251804/4279)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

**According to your comment: "I want the algorithm to run exactly every 5 minutes (for example 14:00; 14:05; 14:10; 14:15......)."**

using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and infinite loop:

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().minute % 5 == 0: 
        #do algorithm
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: This solution is working but there's still a problem, the algorithm will loop during the whole duration of the fifth minute, is there a way to execute it only once?

Comment: Another thing, is there a way to stop the loop without closing the consolle?

Comment: To avoid your first issue I have added a `time.sleep(60)` in every case

Comment: To stop the execution just press 'CTRL + C' in your terminal

Answer (score 2):

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(300 - time.time() % 300)
    crunch_numbers()
```

`crunch_numbers()` is called on 5 minute boundaries defined by `time.time()` clock.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cron job for that if you work in a linux environment. Open the cron tab by

```
crontab -e
```

The following will start a python script cronjob.py every 5th minute of an hour:

```
5 * * * * python /path/to/script/cronjob.py
```

edit: since op specified "want the algorithm to run exactly every 5 minutes":

```
*/5 * * * * python /path/to/script/cronjob.py
```

Comment: This could work but I have some variables that I need to store in the code and that I guess would get back to initiation state if I use this solution

Comment: @DiegoDiTommaso: put this information (that you need "to preserve state between calls") into your question. Mention what do you want to happen if an iteration takes longer than 5 minutes (do you want to skip the next iteration or run two iterations concurrently?). What do you want to happen if the computer time jumps (forward/backwards), if is the computer is suspended -- do you want to skip the corresponding iterations?

Comment: it's not "every five minute" but "every 5th minute of the hour".

Comment: Yes, I need to preserve state between calls, I'm sorry I was not clear in my first message, what I meant is that I want the algorithm to run exactly every 5 minutes (for example 14:00; 14:05; 14:10; 14:15......). The algorithm (retriving the data and cruncing the numbers) itself takes approximatly 12 seconds to be executed. If the computer is suspended I will skip the iteration. Thanks!