# python3 polling routine TCP/IP

Tags: python-3.x, delay, tcp

If we want to have commands sent at predefined intervals in Python3 (let's say one command every sec) are there more elegant ways of achieving this other than the sleep.time() method? 
Furthermore, since it's TCP/IP, which I'm new to, are there other considerations that need to be taken into account? Is there where blocking and non-blocking sockets might come into play?

Comment: For the first part of your question, I would refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python