# Way to repeatedly execute a function without extra modules every x seconds?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Right, I'm quite new and I've been looking around for an answer but I just can't seem to find one that fits me.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python) is pretty much the same as mine, but I need to execute a function every... Let's say 1.2 seconds and without interrupting or blocking the whole while loop.

The reason I won't use modules (except for time) is because the only available ones to me are: *builtins*, *math*, *matplotlib.pyplot*, *numpy*, *operator*, *processing*, *pygal*, *random*, *re*, *string*, *time*, *turtle* and *urllib.request*.

Is there such a way?

Comment: Why don't you have the whole standard library?

Comment: Use a while loop in a thread

Comment: I'm tempted to say 'no' unless you've missed out *threading* (or something with similar capabilities) from your list.

Comment: It's because I'm programming through such a site called [trinket.io](http://trinket.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have turtle available, then you have tkinter available as turtle.TK.  You can then use `root.after(1200, function. args)` to execute `function(*args)` every 1.2 seconds.  Searching SO for `[tkinter] root.after` will give numerous questions with helpful examples.  However, once you do that, you must make everything event driven and event handlers should not take so long as to block the event loop.

EDIT: turtle wraps `tkinter.after` as `turtle.ontimer(function, milleseconds)`.   The function cannot take arguments.  If this is a 'homework' problem of some sort, this may be the intended solution.  There is an example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer).

Comment: Thanks, that'll help me a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module time. You have it on your list.

```
import time
def function():
 print(1)
while True:
 time.sleep(1.2)
 function()
```

Comment: sleep blocks the while loop