# Implementing retry for requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

How do I implement a retry count of 5 times, 10 seconds apart when sending a `POST` request using the `requests` package.
I have found plenty of examples for `GET` requests, just not `post`.

This is what I am working with at the moment, sometimes I get a 503 error. I just need to implement a retry if I get a bad response HTTP code.

```
for x in final_payload:
    post_response = requests.post(url=endpoint, data=json.dumps(x), headers=headers)

#Email me the error
if str(post_response.status_code) not in ["201","200"]:
        email(str(post_response.status_code))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Comment: Retries have nothing specifically to do with GET or POST, so you should easily be able to adapt the examples you found.

Comment: I've used this in the past for GET requests from an external API https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can use [`urllib3.util.retry`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry) module in combination with `requests` to have something as follow:

```
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

def retry_session(retries, session=None, backoff_factor=0.3):
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        method_whitelist=False,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session
```

Usage:

```
session = retry_session(retries=5)
session.post(url=endpoint, data=json.dumps(x), headers=headers)
```

**NB:** You can also inherit from [`Retry`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.retry.Retry) class and customize the retry behavior and retry intervals.

Comment: @DhiaTN - I'm a little confused about this. Assuming this I do `res = session.get(...` - will `res` return immediately in any case? or "wait" until there is either and error or a proper response? What happens if the maximum amount of retries is exceeded?

Comment: you will response anyway, then you have to check the status code to understand if it failed or not

Comment: For me doing the above didn’t work. I used `from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry` instead of `from urllib3.util.retry import Retry`.

Comment: This gives me an error `ValueError: Unable to determine whether fp is closed.`

Answer (score 14):

I found that the default behaviour of Retries did not apply to POST. To do so required the addition of method_whitelist, e.g. below:

```
def retry_session(retries=5):
    session = Session()
    retries = Retry(total=retries,
                backoff_factor=0.1,
                status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
                method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))

    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    return session
```

Comment: You should also be able to do `method_whitelist=False` to allow retry on POST.

Comment: Is there a way I can add custom logging for each retry?