# Adding callback function on each retry attempt using requests/urllib3

Tags: python, callback, python-requests, urllib3

I've implemented a retry mechanism to `requests` session using [`urllib3.util.retry`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry) as suggested both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431044/can-i-set-max-retries-for-requests-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121365/implementing-retry-for-requests-in-python).

Now, I am trying to figure out what is the best way to add a callback function that will be called on every retry attempt.

To explain myself even more, if either the `Retry` object or the requests `get` method had a way to add a callback function, it would have been great. Maybe something like:

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

def retry_callback(url):
    print url   

s = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

url = 'http://httpstat.us/500'
s.get(url, callback=retry_callback, callback_params=[url])
```

I know that for printing url I can use the logging, but this is only a simple example for a more complex use.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can subclass the `Retry` class to add that functionality.

This is the full interaction flow with the `Retry` instance for a given connection attempt:

- `Retry.increment()` is called with the current method, url, response object (if there is one), and exception (if one was raised) whenever an exception is raised, or a 30x redirection response was returned, or the `Retry.is_retry()` method returns true.

  - `.increment()` will re-raise the error (if there was one) and the object was configured not to retry that specific class of errors.
  - `.increment()` calls `Retry.new()` to create an updated instance, with any relevant counters updated and the `history` attribute amended with a new [`RequestHistory()` instance](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.retry.RequestHistory) (a named tuple).
  - `.increment()` will raise a `MaxRetryError` exception if `Retry.is_exhausted()` called on the return value of `Retry.new()` is true. `is_exhausted()` returns true when any of the counters it tracks has dropped below 0 (counters set to `None` are ignored).
  - `.increment()` returns the new `Retry` instance.
- the return value of `Retry.increment()` replaces the old `Retry` instance tracked. If there was a redirect, then `Retry.sleep_for_retry()` is called (sleeping if there was a `Retry-After` header), otherwise `Retry.sleep()` is called (which calls `self.sleep_for_retry()` to honor a `Retry-After` header, otherwise just sleeping if there is a back-off policy). Then a recursive connection call is made with the new `Retry` instance.

This gives you 3 good callback points; at the start of `.increment()`, when creating the new `Retry` instance, and in a context manager around `super().increment()` to let a callback veto an exception or update the returned retry policy on exit.

This is what putting a hook on the start of `.increment()` would look like:

```
import logging

logger = getLogger(__name__)

class CallbackRetry(Retry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._callback = kwargs.pop('callback', None)
        super(CallbackRetry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def new(self, **kw):
        # pass along the subclass additional information when creating
        # a new instance.
        kw['callback'] = self._callback
        return super(CallbackRetry, self).new(**kw)
    def increment(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._callback:
            try:
                self._callback(url)
            except Exception:
                logger.exception('Callback raised an exception, ignoring')
        return super(CallbackRetry, self).increment(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note, the `url` argument is really only the *URL path*, the net location portion of the request is omitted (you'd have to extract that from the `_pool` argument, it has `.scheme`, `.host` and `.port` attributes).

Demo:

```
>>> def retry_callback(url):
...     print('Callback invoked with', url)
...
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> retries = CallbackRetry(total=5, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504], callback=retry_callback)
>>> s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
>>> s.get('http://httpstat.us/500')
Callback invoked with /500
Callback invoked with /500
Callback invoked with /500
Callback invoked with /500
Callback invoked with /500
Callback invoked with /500
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 732, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 732, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 732, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 712, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, response=response, _pool=self)
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in increment
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpstat.us', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /500 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 499, in send
    raise RetryError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.RetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpstat.us', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /500 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))
```

Putting a hook in the `.new()` method would let you adjust the policy for a next attempt, as well as let you introspect the `.history` attribute, but would not let you avoid the exception re-raising.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this detailed answer. 
So if I want to add also a `callback_params` argument, I can do it the same way you did with `callback` and just pass them when I call the callback function itself, right?

Comment: @A.Sarid: yes, you can add any number of additional attributes to your subclass, and use those as you see fit. Do update the `new()` method to copy across any such attributes to the `kw` dictionary before calling the `super().new()` method to create a copy.

Comment: @A.Sarid: Personally, I'd *not* add such a `params` feature. It complicates your callback handling in the class, and is not needed. Instead, pass in a callback function that can handle a default set of arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Yea default set of arguments is fine, but if I want to give those arguments when creating my `CallbackRetry` class, what will be my best option?

Comment: @A.Sarid: you'd have to build an argument list and pass it to the callback with `*args`: `args = [getattr(self, argname) for argname in self.callback_params]` and `self.callback(*args)`. I *strongly* suggest you don't do this. Use a wrapper callback instead, the wrapper accepts all arguments, then calls your actual callback with just `url` or similar: `callback = lambda method, url, *args, **kwargs: real_callback(url)` (in the scenario where `url` is the second argument that the `Retry` subclass will pass in).